# Задать this для promise

Tags: node.js

Здравствуйте.

Использую node.js 0.12.0. В ней есть встроенные promise. Вопрос - возможно ли задать контекст для cb-функции в then? Пример:

```
    var fn = function (arg1, arg2, arg3, cb) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            cb.call('context', null, arg1+arg2+arg3);
        });
    };

    // promisify - функция, принимающая асинхронную функцию и возвращающая функцию, которая вернет promise. 
    //Callback, по прежнему, поддерживается.
    promisify(fn) (1,2,3, function (err, result) {
        console.log('via cb', this, err, result);
    })
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log('via promise', this, result);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error', err);
        });
```

Пример выше выдает

```
via cb context null 6
via promise undefined 6
```

Какие есть варианты, кроме переписывания promise, чтобы и в then был правильный контекст?

Comment:     var p = promisify(fn) (1,2,3);
    p.then(function (result) {
       console.log('via promise', p, result);
    })

но зачем? просто любопытно.
"Использую node.js 0.12.0. В ней есть встроенные promise" прям нативные прям? :)

Comment: @kolpak,

> но зачем?

Перфекционист во мне требует)) Конечно, не критично, но все же..

> "Использую node.js 0.12.0. В ней есть встроенные promise" прям нативные прям? :)

Не понял, что вы имеете в виду?

Блин, не тот пример привел. Счас вопрос исправлю))

Comment: @alvoro, перфекционизм - средство, а не цель. Если this в контексте вопроса не нужен для решения задачи, то и фик с ним.

> Не понял, что вы имеете в виду?

Я так понимаю, ты используешь какой-то пакетик, потому что, насколько я знаю, нативных промисов в ноде нет. Если это так, то стоит покопаться в документации пакета. И, для общего развития, просто в документации https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @kolpak, да нет. Никаких пакетов не ставлю. Из коробки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)