# Потеря контекста вызова

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему после присвоения `var f = obj1.f` теряется контекст вызова и выводится `undefined`?

```js
var obj1 = {

  x: 3,

  f: function() {
    return (this.x);
  }
};

alert(obj1.f());
var f = obj1.f;
alert(f());
```

Comment: Встречный вопрос, а почему вы решили, что контекст вызова должен сохраниться?

Comment: потому что контекст зависит от способа вызова функции и ее создания

Comment: Потому что функции в javascript (в отличие от некоторых других языков) существуют сами по себе, вне привязки к объекту. 

В первом случае Вы вызываете функцию как метод объекта. Во втором случае, достаете функцию из объекта, а после вызываете саму по себе.  

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Коллеги, вопрос валидный, может быть, кто-нибудь даст развёрнутый ответ? Было бы полезно тем, кто не спец в JS (например, мне).

Comment: Я еще не спец в JS(пока), но пользователь Утка дал хорошее объяснение, мне стало все понятно. Так, что спасибо)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky исчерпывающий ответ был дан в комментарии, вот в чем проблема :)

Comment: @VladD вопрос валидный, но ответ на него есть в каждом первом (ну может в каждом втором) учебнике по JS.

Comment: Вынес ответ в ответ

Comment: @AlexeyTen: То же самое я мог бы сказать о половине, если не больше, вопросов по любому тегу :-)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, процентов 80 вопросов по js которые появляются здесь (и на других сайтах) есть в каждом втором учебнике по js. И все равно будут появляться. Не отвечать на них чтоли?

Comment: по хорошему надо закрывать дублями.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, с радостью бы, но для этого надо сделать эталонный ответ на который можно будет с чистой совестью ссылаться. Сможете?)

Comment: @Утка мне очень не хочется переписывать пол-учебника http://learn.javascript.ru/objects-more

Comment: @AlexeyTen к сожалению, насколько я знаю, здесь нельзя закрыть дублем со ссылкой на learn.javascript.ru

Comment: @VladD, попробовал развернуть :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: пожалуйста, обратите внимание на формулировку вопроса...и сравните с кодом который я привел...на каком вы примере вообще собрались обсуждать потерю контекста??? тут в вопросе грубая синтаксическая ошибка, ребята я тут просто новичёк, и мой самый первый и короткий ответ как раз и выявляет проблему приведенного кода, но когда я вижу обсуждение не по сути, и при этом еще и минусуют, извините но мне кажется, что это не правильно. И вопрос должен, для начала, хотя бы работать...что да действительно потеря контекста, тем более на этом примере...

Comment: Cпасибо,  что вопрос сделали, все таки, рабочим >> Выполнить код.  Теперь видно `undefined`, который остаётся, по непонятной причине _потери контекста вызова_.

Comment: @EvgeniyZaritskiy, о том, что функция _возвращает_ `undefined` при выполнении было написано и раньше, в сниппет я его перенес для того, чтобы показать, что тут нет _синтаксической ошибки_, о которой ты говорил в комментариях к своему ответу: код абсолютно рабочий.

Comment: Все просто, для ответа надо понимать работу интерпретатора.
Контекст определяется указателем с которого вызывается.
obj.f - указатель obj
f - указатель document

Comment: Не document, а window (и то не всегда). И отформатируй ответ нормально.

Comment: Было бы очень хорошо принять ответ.

Answer (score 109):

Значение `this` внутри функции зависит от того **как вызывается** функция и **как создана** функция.

### Как вызывается?

Вызвать функцию можно следующими способами:

#### Вызов функции

Если есть обычная функция, в большинстве случаев значением `this` будет глобальный объект (для браузера *window*). При использовании *"strict mode"* - *undefined*.

```js
var f = function (){
  console.log('common:',this.toString());
};
f();

var fStrict = function (){
  "use strict";
  console.log('strict:', this);
};
fStrict();
```

Обычно так вызываются функции обратного вызова(*callback*), вот почему значение *this* в них кажется неожиданным.

Например, при передаче функции в [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), значением *this* будет элемент, которому добавлен обработчик.

---

#### Вызов метода

Метод - это функция находящаяся в объекте.

```js
var Obj = {toString:function(){ return "[object Obj]";}};
Obj.f = function (){
  console.log('common:',this.toString());
};
Obj.f();

Obj.fStrict = function (){
  "use strict";
  console.log('strict:', this.toString());
};
Obj.fStrict();
```

Когда функция вызывается как метод, значением *this* является объект в котором находится функция, фактически значение перед символом точки.

---

#### Вызов конструктора

Функцию можно вызывать в качестве конструктора, для этого перед вызовом нужно использовать оператор [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new): `new Foo()`

```js
function Foo(name){
  this.name = name;
}

var foo = new Foo('foo');
console.log(foo);
```

При вызове функции в качестве конструктора создается новый объект, и значение *this* ссылается на это созданный объект.

**Особенность:** при использовании наследования и [классов из ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) обращение к *this* до вызова [*super*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) в зависимости от браузера вызовет исключение о попытке обратиться к необъявленной/неинициализированной переменной.

```js
class A {}
class B extends A {
  constructor(){
    console.log(this);
  }
}
var b = new B();
```

---

#### Вызов с помощью методов [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) и [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

При использовании функций [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) и [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) можно задать значение *this* напрямую, передав его первым параметром.

```js
var f = function (){
  console.log('common:',this);
};
f.call({o:'object'});

var fStrict = function (){
  "use strict";
  console.log('strict:', this);
};
fStrict.apply({o:'object'});
```

В библиотеках вроде [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) с помощью этих функций вызываются коллбэки передаваемые в различные функции, например: [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [on](http://api.jquery.com/map/) и другие. В качестве *this* в этом случае устанавливается текущий элемент коллекции, либо html-элемент.

---

#### Вызов в качестве коллбэков в функциях обработки массивов

Некоторые встроенные функции для объекта типа `Array` позволяют так же напрямую указать значение *this* для передаваемого коллбэка:

- [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var specialMap = {'b':'specialB','d':'specialD'}
var source= ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var mapped = source.map(function(el){
  return this[el] || ('common-'+el);
},specialMap);

console.log('source:',source);
console.log('mapped:',mapped);
```

### Как создается?

#### Объявление функции или функционального выражения

Обычное объявление функции:

```js
function A(){}

var a = function (){};
```

при обычном объявлении значение *this* определяется при вызове способами описанными выше.

---

#### Создание функции с помощью [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Функция [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) возвращает **новую** *привязанную* функцию. Значение *this*
внутри созданной функции *всегда* то, которое передали при вызове [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

**Важная особенность:** при использовании привязанной функции в качестве конструктора, значение *this* все равно будет указывать на создаваемый объект, как описано выше.

**Важная особенность:** в *НЕ strict mode* при передаче в качестве параметра *this* значений `null` и `undefined` - этот параметр будет проигнорирован и *this* будет установлен в глобальный объект.

```js
function A(){console.log(typeof this,'is window', this === window);}
console.log('execute with null');
A.bind(null)();
console.log('execute with undefined');
A.bind(undefined)();

function A1(){'use strict'; console.log(typeof this, this);}
console.log('execute with null');
A1.bind(null)();
console.log('execute with undefined');
A1.bind(undefined)();
```

**Важная особенность:** значение *this* у созданной функции **нельзя** переопределить используя функции [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) и [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) описанные выше.

```js
function A(){console.log(this);}

var B = A.bind({o:'object'});
console.log('execute binded');
B();
console.log('execute with call');
B.call({another: 'some new object'});

console.log('execute as constructor');
new B();
```

---

#### [Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Стрелочные функции появились в ES2015 и при создании привязываются к текущему значению *this*.

После создания значение *this* нельзя поменять указанными выше способами.

Кроме того стрелочную функцию **нельзя** использовать в качестве конструктора.

```js
function A(){
  this.t = (place)=>console.log(place,this);
}  

var a = new A()
a.t('method:');

var tt = a.t;
tt('free function execute:');

tt.call({o:'object'},'using call function');

new tt('constructor');
```

---

<sub>на основе ответов:</sub>
<sub>- [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)</sub>
<sub>- [*How does “this” keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)</sub>

Comment: Тогда ты ещё не ленился:=:) (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, тогда еще не было вопроса, на который можно сослаться как на дубликат :)

Comment: То что-то не то про null написал: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7YAZ.png

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, в es5 или 6 поменялось поведение :) наверное уберу этот абзац

Comment: @Qwertiy, не, все правильно, обновил ответ :-) в не strict mode - будет глобальный объект, в strict mode - что передали, то и получили. В примере это как раз заметно :)

Comment: @Grundy, так это ж характеристики самой функции, а не bind.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это не характеристики функции, а среды выполнения скорее, strict mode же можно в самом начале файла прописать и тогда для любой функции будет работать так

Comment: @Grundy, если функция, которую биндим находится в строгом режиме, то работает в соответствии с ним. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435547/178988 - там где ссылка на §10.4.3.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103389/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Comment: Предлагаю добавить или просто упомянуть addEventListener в качестве примера «Как вызывается» чтобы можно было смелее вопросы дубликатами отмечать

Comment: @andreymal, обновил

Answer (score 41):

**Вкратце:** в первом случае Вы вызываете функцию как метод объекта, во втором - берете функцию и саму по себе.

**Более многословно:**
Функции в javascript, в отличие от некоторых других популярных языков, являются так называемыми [объектами первого класса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0). То есть они существуют и имеют смысл сами по себе, без привязки к объекту.

Однако иногда возникает естественное желание вызвать функцию как метод какого-то объекта. Это значит, что функции нужен доступ к объекту, методом которого ее хотят сделать, чтобы пользоваться свойствами этого объекта например. Но функция у нас же сама по себе, то есть может вызываться как метод разных объектов, что же делать? Вот для этого было придумано ключевое слово `this`. Это можно понимать как объект, методом которого считается данная функция при данном конкретном вызове.

Вызов функции сразу через точку `myObject.myFunction()` это просто сокращенный способ задания `this` сразу, этакий сахар. Когда Вы вызываете через точку на самом деле происходит примерно следующее:

```
var func = myObject.myFunction; //Получаем функцию-свойство объекта myObject
func.call(myObject); // Вызываем эту функцию с нужным контекстом.
```

Чтобы создать функцию с привязанным контекстом, например для передачи в обработчик, обычно используют bind, например так:

```
var func = myObject.myFunction.bind(myObject);
```

Answer (score 29):

Функция вызывается в контексте объета НЕ потому что она создана внутри объекта.
Она вызывается в контексте объекта, потому что она вызывается как метод obj.func()

Когда функция вызывется как метод, идентификатор this автоматически устанавливается на объект этого метода.

Одна и та же функция может быть вызвана как методы разных объектов.

```
function foo() {
  blah blah
}

x = {}; x.foo=foo; x.foo() //тут this будет установлен на объект х
x2 = {}; x2.foo=foo; x2.foo() //тут this будет установлен на объект х2
foo(); //тут this не будет установлен
```

То же самое если функция изначально создается внутри объекта.Значения не имеет. Имеет значение только то как вызывается данная функция.

Answer (score 18):

В дополнение к другим ответам.

**Если вы пишите на TypeScript**, то можно воспользоваться вот таким декоратором:

```
function bound(target, propertyKey: PropertyKey, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor {
    var value = descriptor.value;

    return {
        configurable: descriptor.configurable,
        enumerable: descriptor.enumerable,

        get() { return value.bind(this); }
    }
}
```

<s>Когда декораторы появятся в Javascript, можно будет написать его и там</s>
При использовании Babel так можно сделать и в Javascript:

```
function bound(target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    var value = descriptor.value;

    return {
        configurable: descriptor.configurable,
        enumerable: descriptor.enumerable,

        get() { return value.bind(this); }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
class Foo {
    private readonly _baz;

    constructor(baz) {
        this._baz = baz;
    }

    @bound bar() {
         console.log(this._baz);
    }
}

var bar = new Foo(42).bar;
bar(); // 42
```

---

Если принципиально чтобы последовательные обращения к свойству выдавали одинаковые значения (например, дабы избежать избыточных рендеров в React) - придется написать чуть более сложный код:

```
var bfmc = Symbol("boundFunctionsMemoizedCache");

function bound(target, propertyKey: PropertyKey, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor {
    return {
        enumerable: descriptor.enumerable,

        get() {
            if (!this.hasOwnProperty(bfmc))
                this[bfmc] = {};

            if (this[bfmc].hasOwnProperty(propertyKey))
                return this[bfmc][propertyKey];

            return this[bfmc][propertyKey] = descriptor.value.bind(this);
        }
    }
}
```

В принципе, можно написать и чуть проще (например, создавать отдельный символ на каждый вызов bound или вообще переопределять свойство propertyKey) - но я не уверен что такой код сможет быть правильно оптимизирован и не наплодит кучу скрытых классов где не надо. Буду рад услышать замечания по этому поводу от того, кто уже сталкивался с оптимизациями Javascript под конкретные браузеры.

---

Замечание. Этот ответ показывает устаревшую старую версию декораторов, которая никогда не войдет в стандарт.

Comment: `var a = new Foo(7);
console.log(a.bar === a.bar);` - будет false. Можно улучшить так, чтобы было true?

Comment: В реакте PureComponent будет пересчитываться из-за таких изменений, а это плохо. Да и вообще, ну логично же, что должна возвращаться ссылка на одну и ту же функцию, а не создаваться клон бинда на каждом вызове - вдруг она у меня в цикле 1000000 раз вызывается.

Comment: @Qwertiy замечание принимается. Дописал ответ.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz обратите внимание, на дополнение

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а там нельзя как-нибудь value присобачить вместо get?

Comment: @Qwertiy совсем без get обойтись нельзя

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а, это же тоже в класс попадает, а не в инстанс - в этом дело? А в инстанс его нельзя отправить?

Comment: @Qwertiy оно в прототип попадает. Нет, в инстанс его отправить нельзя (видел где-то инциализаторы - но они то ли в стандарт не вошли, то ли от них отказались)

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы создаете обьект - вы по сути создаете его контекст, this внутри обьекта ссылается на контекст обьекта.
После присвоения данной функции обычной переменной - вы сами же вырываете функцию из её контекста, тем самым привязка this внутри данной функции теряется, под this теперь имеется ввиду обьект window.
Тоесть обращаясь к this.x теперь на самом деле вы обращаетесь к window.x который и есть undefined.

Сама операция присвоения функции привязаной к обьекту, внешней переменной - это не совсем логически выглядит, функция не может "помнить" о том что когда-то она была в обьекте, поэтому должна использовать его контекст для поиска атрибутов