# Вопрос про контекст при вызове функции из объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, кусочек на jquery - все хорошо работает (первая кнопка), но если кликнуть на вторую кнопку, к которой событие регистрируется при помощи addEventListener, то теряю контекст, that - это кнопка, this - объект опций ajax.

Как тогда при клике по второй кнопке вызвать `_.setText()` изнутри `getAjax()` ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(function() {

  var _ = {
    initJquery: function() {
      var that = this;
      $('#one').on('click', function() {
        that.getAjax();
      });
    },

    initJs: function() {
      $('#two')[0].addEventListener('click', this.getAjax);

    },

    setText: function(text) {
      $('.update').html(text);
    },

    getAjax: function() {
      var that = this;
      $.ajax({
          url: 'txt.txt',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'text'
        })
        .done(function(resp) {
          console.log('this');
          console.log(this);
          console.log('that');
          console.log(that);

          // при нажатии первой кнопки всё хорошо
          // тут теряю контекст при нажатии второй кнопки addEventListener
          that.setText(resp);
        })
        .fail(function() {
          console.log("error");
        });

    }
  };

  _.initJquery();
  _.initJs();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="one" value="Кнопка 1">
<input type="button" id="two" value="Кнопка 2">
<div class="update"></div>
```

**Результат**

Всем спасибо, разобрался. Надо было так:

```
.done(function() {
    this.setText(resp);
}.bind(this))
```

Итоговый код такой:

```
$(function() {

  var _ = {
    initJquery: function() {
      $('#one').on('click', function() {
        this.getAjax();
      }.bind(this));
    },

    initJs: function() {
      $('#two')[0].addEventListener('click', this.getAjax.bind(this));

    },

    setText: function(text) {
      $('.update').html(text);
    },

    getAjax: function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'txt.txt',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'text'
        })
        .done(function(resp) {
          console.log('this');
          console.log(this);
          this.setText(resp);
        }.bind(this))
        .fail(function() {
          console.log("error ajax");
        }.bind(this));

    }
  };

  _.initJquery();
  _.initJs();

});
```

Comment: this.getAjax.bind(this)

Comment: А если точнее    $('#two')[0].addEventListener('click', this.getAjax.bind(this));

Вообще, это конечно вопрос стиля и конвенций проекта, но лично я стараюсь писать как можно больше bind и стрелочных функций и как можно меньше me/self/that.

Comment: Bind - это полезно, но его использование не всегда возможно и оправданно.  По хорошему, выбранная архитектура кода в данном случае - не удачная. Здесь бы простые функции прописать, да и вызывать их когда надо.

Comment: @zhenyab мне кажется bind / meselfthat - чисто вопрос договоренностей. Я писал несколько проектов на ext и несколько на backbone-based фреймворках. В ext - везде писали me/self/that, в бэкбоне везде bind. Это раз. Во вторых, в выбранном примере нет архитектуры, это очевидно минимальный воспроизводимый пример, искуственный.

Comment: Полемику разводить не буду по поводу bind, а в примере есть определенный pattern (как по-русски красивее сказать?) в общем pattern я бы заменил :)

Comment: да, это типа учебный код.

Comment: @Утка да, но при `$('#two')[0].addEventListener('click', this.getAjax.bind(this));` работает только с `var that = this;`

Comment: @Jean-Claude, ну да, я не стал править весь ваш код, внес минимальные изменения. Просто сказал что вообще можно везде прибиндить, Вы можете это сами сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Кратко:**

```
 $('#two')[0].addEventListener('click', this.getAjax.bind(this));
```

**Почему у вас не работает?**
Как я [здесь пытался объяснить совсем недавно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/535165#535165), функция существует сама по себе, без привязанного к ней объекта. В callback передается сама функция, как самостоятельная сущность. Информации о том, с чем ее связать не передается. То что слева от точки служит лишь для того, чтобы эту функцию найти. А `this`, как раз означает какой-то объект, методом которого функцию мы считаем, поэтому он и становится undefined (или window в нестрогом режиме).

**Что же делать?**
Передать в callback не просто функцию, а функцию и контекст. Для этого обычно используется метод [bind](http://learn.javascript.ru/bind), который создает обертку необходимой нам функции с привязанным контекстом. Когда мы эту обертку вызываем, она вызывает ваш метод с контекстом который прибиндили.

Вообще везде где вы сохраняете контекст через `var that = this` можно сохранить его и через `bind`. Это вопрос договоренностей в конкретном проекте, но лично я предпочитаю так. А в некоторых местах вообще удобнее использовать es6 arrow functions, которые не создают своего отдельного `this`.

Ваша первая функция с `bind`

```
initJquery: function() {
  $('#one').on('click', function() {
    this.getAjax();
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Она же (почти) со стрелочками:

```
initJquery: function() {
        $('#one').on('click', () => this.getAjax());
}
```

Comment: `arrow functions` ещё не везде поддерживаются, так что лучше их пока не использовать, либо использовать скомпилированными сборщиками

Comment: да, именно поэтому пока стрелочные трогать не буду. (ещё не везде поддерживаются)

Comment: @Jean-Claude, если у вас есть какая-то сборка, то транспилер к ней добавляется элементарно

Comment: @Утка не, пока я не умею этого. Итоговый код имеет вид http://jsbin.com/kojefilaxi/edit?html,output но без var that = this; он не работает, как убрать that в getAjax() ?

Comment: @Утка вроде разобрался: `.done(function() {
 this.setText(resp);
}.bind(this))`