# arrow function и .bind

Tags: javascript

```
(function(){
    const requestBtn = d.getElementById('reqestInfo');
    requestBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ console.log(this) }, false)
})()
```

и надо привязать this к requestBtn

```
(function(){
    const requestBtn = d.getElementById('reqestInfo');
    requestBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ console.log(this) }.bind(requestBtn), false)
})()
```

дает синтаксическю ошибку,но

```
(function(){
    const requestBtn = d.getElementById('reqestInfo');
    requestBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){ console.log(this) }, false)
})()
```

получаеться правильно. Насколько я понимаю `arrow func` так же привязывают this к контексту или я что-то путаю

Comment: не совсем уверен, что дубликат, но помочь данный вопрос должен: [Потеря контекста вызова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: я как раз смотрел этот вопрос, и там в принцыпе есть обьяснение но оно обьясняеться гранью между функциональным джс и обьектным, т.к по всех примерах присутствует присвоения какой то переменной ф-ии. А вот в случае с анонимными ф-ми - вопрос

Comment: не, там абсолютно то же самое, не важно присвоили ли функцию переменной и вызывали или вызывали сразу при объявлении, поведение одно и то же

Comment: хм нашел, После создания значение this нельзя поменять указанными выше способами. тогда придется делать более старым вариантом..

Comment: Написал ответ, но мне все больше кажется, что действительно дубликат.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стрелочные функции привязываются к **текущему** контексту.

#### Что это значит?

Это значит, что внутри функции будет значение `this` будет таким же, как и в момент создания.

Рассмотрим примеры из вопроса:

```
(function(){
    const requestBtn = d.getElementById('reqestInfo');
    requestBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ console.log(this) }, false)
})()
```

Данный код выполняется внутри самовызывающейся функции. Внутри такой функции `this` -> глобальный объект, в данном случае `window`. Следовательно внутри обработчика, этот `this` сохранится.

Второй пример:

```
(function(){
    const requestBtn = d.getElementById('reqestInfo');
    requestBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ console.log(this) }.bind(requestBtn), false)
})()
```

Здесь действительно синтаксическая ошибка, чтобы ее исправить нужно обернуть стрелочную функцию в круглые скобки

```
(()=>{ console.log(this) }).bind(requestBtn)
```

Но и это не поможет, так как у стрелочных функций **нельзя** сменить контекст, полученный при создании.

Теперь, почему работает последний пример:

```
(function(){
    const requestBtn = d.getElementById('reqestInfo');
    requestBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){ console.log(this) }, false)
})()
```

Потому что, при добавлении обработчика через функцию *addEventListener*, обработчик вызывается в контексте добавленного элемента. То есть, это по сути нормальное поведение, когда `this` внутри обработчика ссылается на элемент, и все пляски со сменой контекста обычно обусловлены тем, что в обработчике в качестве `this` хотелось видеть, не элемент, а какой-нибудь сторонний объект.