# Помогите разобрать до конца код

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="menu">
<button data-action="save">Сохранить</button>
<button data-action="load">Загрузить</button>
<button data-action="search">Поиск</button>
</div>

<script>
function Menu(elem) {
this.save = function() {
  alert( 'сохраняю' );
};
this.load = function() {
  alert( 'загружаю' );
};
this.search = function() {
  alert( 'ищу' );
};

var self = this;     // зачем тут this, объясните пожалуйста дав полноценный ответ

elem.onclick = function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var action = target.getAttribute('data-action');
  if (action) {
    self[action]();  // как работает это выражение?
  }
};
}

new Menu(menu);
```

Comment: @КонстантинБашаркевич - ему непонятно - 1. что такое `this` при вызове функции как конструктора, 2. что такое замыкание (closure), где переменная `self` доступна в обработчике `onclick`, a `this` в этом обработчике, отличается от `this` в `Menu`.

Comment: @Igor да, я на комментарии не сразу обратил внимание, прошу прощения

Comment: а остальной код, кроме этих двух строчек понятен?

Comment: Да, с остальным кодом я разобрался.

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае функция `Menu` используется в качестве конструктора. При ее вызове с оператором `new`: `new Menu(menu)`, внутри нее `this` указывает на новый создаваемый объект.

Внутри обработчика клика, `this` уже будет указывать на элемент, по которому кликнули и чтобы вызывать внутри обработчика методы создаваемого объекта `Menu`, ссылка на этот объект сохраняется в переменную `self`, которая и используется внутри обработчика.

Подробнее про потерю контекста можно узнать в вопросе: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

---

Для обращения к полям объекта в яваскрипте предусмотрено две нотации

1. [Dot-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) - обращение к полю через точку

   ```
   var o = {
     prop: 1;
   };
   o.prop;// 1
   ```

   Данная нотация широко распространена, но имеет ограничения на имена полей, к которым может быть применена. Так, для использования этой нотации, имя поля должно быть валидным идентификатором.
2. [Bracket-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) - обращение к полю с использованием скобок `[]`

   ```
   var o = {
     prop: 1;
   };
   o["prop"];// 1
   ```

   Данная нотация широко применяется, в случаях, когда имя поля, к которому нужно обратиться не известно заранее, а также, когда имя поля не является валидным идентификатором, а является например числом, либо содержит пробел.

В данном случае, как раз имя свойства определяется в момент клика, и выполняется соответствующая функция.

---

Без промежуточной переменной можно обойтись, если использовать [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
function Menu(elem) {
  this.save = function() {
    console.log('сохраняю');
  };
  this.load = function() {
    console.log('загружаю');
  };
  this.search = function() {
    console.log('ищу');
  };

  elem.onclick = (e) => {
    var target = e.target;
    var action = target.getAttribute('data-action');
    if (action) {
      this[action]();
    }
  };
}

new Menu(menu);
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-action="save">Сохранить</button>
  <button data-action="load">Загрузить</button>
  <button data-action="search">Поиск</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто. Но все же думаю, не стоит поощрять авторов подобными ответами:)

Comment: @dDevil, вообще, если б можно было сразу отметить как дубликат двух вопросов - я бы отметил :-)

Comment: Удивлён что никто не отметил - неявное создание ссылок на элементы с `id` браузером использовать никак не стоит.

Comment: @Other, мне кажется в данном случае это не имеет значения

Comment: Всё же - если кто-то просит объяснения, нужно дать ему как можно больше знаний, а эти переменные - довольно коварный хак, о котором стоит знать. Хотя это Ваш ответ - пишите что хотите :)

Comment: @Other, уже написал, и так не мало получилось

Comment: И всё же кажется с водой перебор.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Menu(elem) {
    this.save = function() {
        alert( 'сохраняю' );
    };

    this.load = function() {
        alert( 'загружаю' );
    };

   this.search = function() {
       alert( 'ищу' );
   };

   var self = this;  // тут self будет равен объекту данной функции (класса) Menu

   elem.onclick = function(e) {
       var target = e.target;
       var action = target.getAttribute('data-action'); // данные атрибута в котором записано имя метода
       if ( action ) {
           self[action]();  // вызываем метод нашего объекта Menu
       }
   };
}

new Menu(menu);
```

Описал то что спрашивали ))

Comment: Почему self будет равен именно объекту, как он на него указывает?

Comment: Функция Menu вызывается как объект new Menu. Ну а в self мы записываем this что является ссылкой на родительский объект.

Comment: То есть по сути если бы функция Main не вызывалась как объект, то переменная self указывала на window?

Comment: Вообще тут self указывает на объект не только потому что функция у нас вызывается как объект, но еще и потому что ее тут перезаписали, если бы записали вот так _self то получилось бы что ссылка на объект записалась бы в простую переменную, и self сохранил бы свое первоначальное значение. Надеюсь я никого не запутал ))

Answer (score 1):

Внутри второй функции будет свой this, не имеющий ничего общего с this из "верхнего" кода. Для доступу к этому "верхнему" this мы и объявили переменную. Не найдя такой переменной js внутри функции, js полезет наверх, и упрётся в эту "глобальную"(в данном контексте) переменную self

Comment: про выражение неверно, в коде даже массива нет

Comment: @Grundy, просветите меня тогда пожалуйста:). Могу предположить, что это динамический вызов одной из функции save, load, search. Если так, дайте пожалуйста статью поподробнее про это. Если нет - все равно расскажите:)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, минутка педантичности)) В JavaScript нет ассоциативных массивов, в нем есть "объекты, которые ведут себя как ассоциативные массивы" или другими словами "хеш таблицы". И это не выражение, а обращение к свойствам объектам или доступ к элементам хеш таблицы по ключу. Поэтому правильней говорить не массив, а объект. И не выражение, а доступ к свойству объекта. Как-то так: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Comment: @AlexKrass почаще бы такие минутки). Спасибо)

Comment: Я все же не до конца понимаю. Почему переменная self указывает именно на объект, а не на window? Прошу прощение если сильно примитивный вопрос, я просто еще не опытный.

Comment: @Игорь, [ключевое слово this](http://javascript.ru/this) указывает на контекст исполнения. Внутри функции на саму функцию `Main`, а при использовании обработчиков на объект `window`. В данном случае пока находимся в функции сохраняем контекст `Main` в промежуточную переменную и используем уже ее не теряя контекст. Поэтому внутри `self` все так же ссылается на `Main` т.к. мы ее сохранили выше, а вот сама `this` ссылается на `window`. Подробнее читайте про области видимости в JS и замыканиях.