# Как получить значение json

Tags: javascript, json

Есть json.

```js
wt = {
"days": [{
 "2": [{"1":"1","2":"2","4":"4","6":"6"}],
 "3": [{"1":"1","3":"3","7":"7"}]
}],
"time_from_h": [{
 "2": [{"1":"8","2":"9","4":"8","6":"10"}],
 "3": [{"1":"8","3":"9","7":"8"}]
}],
"time_from_m": [{
 "2": [{"1":"0","2":"5","4":"30","6":"50"}],
 "3": [{"1":"10","3":"0","7":"10"}]
}],
"time_to_h": [{
 "2": [{"1":"21","2":"20","4":"22","6":"20"}],
 "3": [{"1":"19","3":"17","7":"19"}]
}],
"time_to_m": [{
 "2": [{"1":"30","2":"40","4":"40","6":"30"}],
 "3": [{"1":"59","3":"10","7":"40"}]
}]
}
```

Как обратится к:
wt.days.2.4 (получить именно значение элемента)

Как проверить, если ли wt.days.2

Т.е. будет функция, в которую будет передаваться id. Так вот надо проверить, если в id=2 в wt.days и если есть, то вывести wt.days.2.4

Comment: Неясно, для чего у Вас там объекты обернуты в массивы из одного элемента, но как-то вот так: `var i = 2; console.log(wt.days[0][i] ? wt.days[0][i][0][4] : undefined);`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите разобрать до конца код](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552386/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: @Grundy, на закрытый вопрос ссылка-то ведет.

Comment: @Visman, это не делает его _не_ дубликатом

Answer (score 1):

```js
var wt = {
"days": [{
 "2": [{"1":"1","2":"2","4":"4","6":"6"}],
 "3": [{"1":"1","3":"3","7":"7"}]
}],
"time_from_h": [{
 "2": [{"1":"8","2":"9","4":"8","6":"10"}],
 "3": [{"1":"8","3":"9","7":"8"}]
}],
"time_from_m": [{
 "2": [{"1":"0","2":"5","4":"30","6":"50"}],
 "3": [{"1":"10","3":"0","7":"10"}]
}],
"time_to_h": [{
 "2": [{"1":"21","2":"20","4":"22","6":"20"}],
 "3": [{"1":"19","3":"17","7":"19"}]
}],
"time_to_m": [{
 "2": [{"1":"30","2":"40","4":"40","6":"30"}],
 "3": [{"1":"59","3":"10","7":"40"}]
}]
};

console.log(wt.days[0][2][0][4]); // странная запись из-за того, что объекты содержат массивы, а массивы содержат объекты, отсюда и нулевые индексы
console.log(typeof wt.days[0][2]); // элемент 2 есть
console.log(typeof wt.days[0][4]); // элемента 4 нет, "undefined"
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как правильнее записать такую структуру?

Comment: Какую именно? Если вы про `wt`, то вам нужно из нее исключить массивы (квадратные скобки) и оставить только объекты (фигурные скобки), тогда лишние индексы (нулевые) при обращении к нужным элементам структуры не понадобятся.