# Не могу понять роль нуля в данном контексте. JS

Tags: javascript

Прежде чем перейти сюда чтобы задать вопрос, я честно на протяжении часа гуглил, но не смог найти ответов, хоть и в некоторых ссылках встречалось похожее. Вопрос следующий - что в *JS* значит ноль в следующей конструкции:

```
var n = (0, window.unescape)("somestring");
```

Буду благодарен за ответ или ссылку где прочитать можно.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

в данном случае он ничего не значит и вместо него могло быть что угодно. Нужен он тут для срабатывания оператора *запятая*.

При таком применении оператора запятой можно получить ссылку на метод оторванный от текущего контекста и при вызове его будет использован глобальный контекст. В данном случае *window*.

То есть, запись в вопросе эквивалентна следующей

```
var unescape = window.unescape;
var n = unescape("something");
```

Учитывая, что в данном случае всегда функция будет вызываться в глобальном контексте нет смысла это делать и можно обойтись обычным вызовом

```
var n = window.unescape("somestring");
```

---

Пример когда это имеет смысл

```js
var a = {
  func: function() {
    console.log('eval context is window: ', (0, eval)("this") === window);
    console.log('eval context is current object: ', eval("this") === a);
  },
  func1: function() {
    console.log('context: ', this.toString());
  }
}

a.func();
(1, a.func1)();
(a.func1)();
```

Comment: Почему запятая меняет контекст? Определённо капкан архитектуры `JS`.

Comment: Еще бы ссылку на подробное описание данного оператора добавить, а то я тоже узнал для себя что-то новое =)

Comment: @Other, контекст меняет не запятая, а именно ее такое применение. по сути это оператор который возвращает последний операнд, в данном случае это ссылка на метод, то есть мы взяли эту ссылку и вернули и дальше сразу вызвали ее.

Comment: Я понял что возвращает, но почему это происходит? Понимаю если `0 || func`, например, но тут что?

Comment: Ндаа, забавный оператор [Оператор запятая](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#оператор-запятая)

Comment: @Other, вот сейчас я не понял :-) я в ответе написал эквивалент: сохранение метода в переменную и затем выполнение, вот тут то же самое. если вопрос вообще: почему контекст меняется тут можно посмотреть вопрос: [Потеря контекста вызова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: Почитал по ссылке уважаемого @КонстантинБашаркевич [`Запятая позволяет перечислять выражения, разделяя их запятой ','. Каждое из них – вычисляется и отбрасывается, за исключением последнего, которое возвращается.`] и понял что и почему, благодарю за Ваше пояснение по теме.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ, многое встало на свои места, собственно данный код попал мне в руки в результате долгой и мучительной деобфускации.

Comment: @Other из подобного в голову сразу приходит метод prog_match_replace() из php, позволявший при использовании модификатор \e исполнять найденные на замену строки как код в контексте сервера. С версии 5.5 deprecated.

Comment: @justyx, особой связи не вижу, хотя флаг `e` меня насторожил в своё время. Как и всё из группы `eval`, впрочем.