# Как работает конструкция (num, num, num)?

Tags: javascript

или так

```
var a  = (1,4,5,7); 
console.log(a); // 7
```

Не понимаю, почему в итоге a = 7.

Comment: [Оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)

Comment: Спасибо, крутая фича)))

Comment: Но с ней надо быть аккуратным, а то [может быть и такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554719/186999)