# Контекст объекта JS

Tags: javascript

Есть конструктор объекта:

```
function ServisePlate(plate) {
    this.elem = plate;
    this.header = plate.querySelector('.servises_content_header');
    this.body = plate.querySelector('.servises_content_text');
    this.settings = {
        step: 30,
        speed: 10
    }
    var self = this;

}
```

И метод:

```
ServisePlate.prototype.showBody = function() {
    console.log(this.elem.offsetHeight);
    console.log(this.body.offsetHeight);
    if(this.elem.offsetHeight < this.body.offsetHeight + 100) {
        this.elem.style.height = this.elem.offsetHeight + this.settings.step + 'px';
        setTimeout(self.showBody, this.settings.speed);
    }
}
```

при создании объектов и запуске функции

```
var box = document.querySelector('.servises');

var plates = [].slice.apply(box.querySelectorAll('.servises_content'));
for(var i = 0; i < plates.length; i++) {
   plates[i] = new ServisePlate (plates[i]);
   plates[i].showBody();
}
```

Не отрабатывает тайм аут... т.е строчка:

```
this.elem.style.height = this.elem.offsetHeight + this.settings.step + 'px';
```

выполняется и на этом все!!! При этом в консоль ошибки не падают.
Подскажите где ошибка?

Comment: Без вглядывания в код предрекаю что надо что-то вроде: setTimeout(this.showBody.bind(this), this.settings.speed);

Comment: Возможно вам поможет вот это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0
Или вот это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566696/%D0%B2-nodejs-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-undefined-typescript#comment741361_566696

Comment: Ну и добавлю, что self из конструктора вам не будет просто так виден в методе, но подозреваю что он туда попал уже в процессе лихорадочной отладки

Comment: UPD: во второй ссылке сослался на коммент ане на вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566696/%D0%B2-nodejs-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-undefined-typescript

Comment: @Утка, контексты мне пока  трудновато даются.... подскажите пожалуйста еще такой момент:
Я собираюсь повесить обработчик на клик на контейнер затем проверять куда кликнули и запускать этот метод если клик был на объекте.... так вот в обработчике события this потеряет контекст... как мне правильней сослаться на объект?

Comment: Не понял. Возможно вам стоит задать отдельный вопрос с иллюстрирующим примером.

Comment: "this потеряет контекст" - this, это и есть контекст =) Потерять контекст может метод (то есть значение this). Можно создать метод-обертку черзе bind с привязанным контекстом, тогда он не потеряется

Comment: Внимательно прочитайте вот это: http://learn.javascript.ru/bind