# Почему переменная this, внутри функции callback, будет хранить то же самое значение, что и второй параметр domElement, который в нее передается?

Tags: jquery

Привет.

Рассмотрим пример.

```js
var heights = [];  // переменная, которая будет хранить высоты элементов
$("div").each(function(indx, element){
 heights.push($(element).height());
});
// в итоге, в переменную heights будут помещены значения высот всех div-элементов
```

Нужно отметить, что переменная *this*, внутри функции *callback*, будет хранить то же самое значение, что и второй параметр domElement, который в нее передается. Таким образом, предыдущий пример мог выглядеть следующим образом:

```js
var heights = [];  // переменная, которая будет хранить высоты элементов
$("div").each(function(indx){
  heights.push($(this).height());
});
// в итоге, в переменную heights будут помещены значения высот всех div-элементов
```

**Вопрос - ПОЧЕМУ переменная this, внутри функции callback, будет хранить то же самое значение, что и второй параметр domElement, который в нее передается?**

*this* ссылается на объект, в котором лежит функция. Я вообще не понимаю, ГДЕ эта анонимная функция лежит (в какой объект она вложена). Если имею дело с обычной функцией, то я знаю, ГДЕ я ее объявил (внутри какого объекта), соответственно, знаю, куда будет ссылаться свойство *this*, когда пойдет отрабатывать локальный код функции.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: конкретно для jquery: [`callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] )`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/6acf4a79467a5aea5bc1eb7d552d72366718635d/src/core.js#L304) и [`callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] )`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/6acf4a79467a5aea5bc1eb7d552d72366718635d/src/core.js#L310)

Comment: @Jean-Claude, как минимум два линка в комментарии выше.

Comment: я все равно ничего не понял

Comment: @Dimon, потому что надо прочитать в вопросе/ответах по ссылке, как определяется какой контекст (значение this внутри функции) будет у функции и от чего это зависит. А далее следует посмотреть в исходники jQuery и заметить, что callback вызывается с помощью функции [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: @Grundy пардон, на ссылки не обратил внимание. вы две ссылки грубо говоря на одно и то же дали, не имели ли в в виду сам метод each() https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/6acf4a79467a5aea5bc1eb7d552d72366718635d/src/core.js#L92 , который возвращает $.each() и откуда понятно что куда передается?

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за ответ. теперь я разобрался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому, что у объекта `Function` в JavaScript есть метод `call`, вызывая который, можно передать в функцию любой `this`

Comment: да и bind....... но вроде он не про это

Comment: @Jean-Claude, да, bind не про это, он связывает контекст с функцией, а не вызывает ее