# React - биндинг и ключи

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть два терзающий вопроса:

1. Есть кусок кода рендера

   ```
   var data = this.props.data;
       var hidden = this.state.hidden;
       var template = data.map(function(item,index) {
       return(
           <div className="mainDiv" key="{index}">
               <p className="feedText">{item.author}</p>
               <p className={'feedText ' + 'smallmargin'}>{item.text}</p>
               <p className={'feedText ' + 'smallmargin ' + (hidden ? '' : 'hidden')}>{item.bigtext}</p>
           </div>
       )
   });
   ```

   Реакт отказывается рендерить по причине {index} используется дважды,должен быть уникален,но значение индекса ведь разные - 0 и 1. Как быть в такой ситуации?
2. Как привязать событие? Есть событие

   ```
   divClick : function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       this.setState({hidden : true});
   }
   ```

   Банальный онклик говорит,что divClick undefined

   ```
   <div className="mainDiv" onClick={this.divClick}>
   ```

В чем тут проблемы?

Comment: Разные вопросы стоит задавать в разных вопросах ;)

Comment: onClick={this.divClick.bind(this)} или onClick={::this.divClick} не решит проблему?

Comment: @arnage. Разумеется нет. Это все равно что написать undefined.bind(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**По вопросу 1**, это ваша опечатка:

Вы написали:

```
key="{index}"
```

Соответственно ключом становится строка. Фигурные скобки внутри строки в jsx-это просто фигурные скобки, то что внутри них не является js-выражением.

Надо:

```
key={index}
```

Ну или 
   `key = {index.toString()}` если вам прямо так уж строка нужна(нет не нужна)

**По вопросу 2**, при правильном использовании должно работать.
Приведите весь код компонента. То есть весь кусок в котором не работает, целиком.
Мой хрустальный шар предполагает, что Вы теряете контекст (this) в методе `.map`
Попробуйте так:

```
var template = data.map(function(item,index) {/** где-то здесь мы вызываем this.divClick **/}.bind(this))
```

Подробнее про контекст почитать можно например [в ответах к этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/535165).

Comment: Thats it!Ваш хрустальный шар сработал.Спасибо большое!Действительно опечатался с объектом,а насчет bind(this) я конечно не подумал.Еще раз спасибо