# forEach для работы с массивами

Tags: javascript

Это аналог работы метода `forEach`. Метод `forEach`, как известно, может принимать следующие параметры `(callback[, thisArg])`. Вот функция, которая является аналогом данного метода.

Как добавить еще и параметр `thisArg` (Необязательный параметр. Значение, используемое в качестве `this` при вызове функции `callback`)?

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
console.log(customForEach(array, func));

function customForEach(src, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    callback(src[i], i, src);
  }
}

function func(item, i, arr) {
  console.log(i + ' Элемент: ' + item + '(массив ' + arr + ')');
}
```

Comment: `console.log(customForEach(array, func));` - Что Вы ожидаете увидеть в консоли?

Comment: что-то по типу callback.call(thisArg, src[i], i, src). Функцию вызвать в нужном контексте - методы apply и call, думаю причина вопроса в незнании что такое есть)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Читаю MDN и не могу понять) Пытаюсь разобраться на конкретном примере.

Comment: заодно можно посмотреть ответы на вопрос: [потеря контекста вызова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/536020#536020)

Comment: @Igor для первого элемента массива "0 Элемент: 1(массив 1,2,3,4,5,6)" и так далее.

Answer (score 2):

При использовании функций [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) и [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) можно задать значение *this* напрямую, передав его первым параметром.

Разница между этими методами в способе передачи параметров:

1. Если количество параметров известно заранее, то проще использовать функцию [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), в которой параметры вызываемой функции указываются через запятую

   ```
   callback.call(thisArg, src[i], i, src);
   ```
2. Если список параметров собирается динамически, то лучше использовать [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), которая вторым параметром принимает *array-like* объект либо массив с передаваемыми параметрами.

   ```
   callback.apply(thisArg, [src[i], i, src]);
   ```

Пример:

```js
var o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
console.log('Пример с передачей this');
customForEach(Object.keys(o), func, o);

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
console.log('Пример без передачи this');
customForEach(array, func2);

function customForEach(src, callback, thisArg) {
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    callback.call(thisArg, src[i], i, src);
  }
}

function func(item, i, arr) {
  console.log(i + ' Элемент: ' + item + '(массив ' + arr + ')' + ', значение: ' + this[item] + '(this:' + JSON.stringify(this) + ')');
}

function func2(item, i, arr) {
  console.log(i + ' Элемент: ' + item + '(массив ' + arr + ')');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Подробнее про смену контекста можно узнать в вопросе:

[**Потеря контекста вызова**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0?noredirect=1&lq=1)