# Функция, которая аналог метода forEach

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
customForEach(array, funcForEach);
function customForEach(src, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    console.log(callback(src, i, src[i]));
  }
}
function funcForEach(src, index, item) {
  var res = `Элемент ${item} массива [${src}] имеет индекс ${index}`;
  return res;
}
```

Строго в учебных целях нужно написать функцию, которая будет являться аналогом метода `forEach`. Почти полный аналог получился, за исключением того, что нет необязательного параметра `thisArg`. Каким образом его дописать в мой код?

Comment: вот тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach есть реализация этого полифила :)

Comment: .call, .apply, выбирайте что больше нравится

Comment: @Sublihim я туда как раз и смотрю, но не понимаю, как это могу применять к своему коду.

Comment: Также вам может помочь этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020/14963

Comment: С помощью call или apply вы можете вызвать свой колбек в нужном контексте

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, даже не знаю стоит ли закрыть как дубликат

Comment: http://jsraccoon.ru/fn-array-methods  mojet pomojet

Comment: @Grundy, я не стал жать "закрыть" потому что думаю "ща придет Гранди и грохнет или ответ напишут быстрее" =)

Comment: @Grundy, ладно, пусть живет на самом деле, тот вопрос "почему" а не "как" =)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, не все-таки про то, _как_ устанавливать там тоже объяснено.