# JavaScript | Прототипирование, застрял немножко

Tags: javascript

Написал такую штуку: 
Вопросы собственно в коде.

```js
var Person = {
 constructor: function(name, age, gender) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  return this; //Что тут возвращает this? Все аргументы из фунцкии или что?
 },
};

/*________________________*/


var WebDeveloper = Object.create(Person); //Тут пока всё более-менее понятно
WebDeveloper.constructor = function(name, age, gender, skills) {
 Person.constructor.apply(this, arguments); //что делает apply? я читал, что устанавливает значение this в функции. Отсюда и вопрос: разве this это типо не ключевое слово а-ля var? 
 this.skills = skills || []; //что собственно тут устанавливается? skills или массив? пустой? и когда сработает skills, а когда массив? значение skills внутри функции теперь становится и значением skills которая за пределами функции - это я понял. ну а метод apply тут причем?
 return this;
};

var developer = Object.create(WebDeveloper).constructor("Jack", 21, "male", ["html", "css", "js", "php", "mysql"]);
```

Comment: Есть такая вещь как `console.log`

Comment: а зачем оно мне? или Вам нужно ?

Comment: Вам оно для `console.log(this)` например

Comment: `person.constructor.apply(this, arguments);` -> `Person.constructor.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: [немного о том как работает this](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020/186999)

Comment: строка со skills просто вариант установки значения по умолчанию, если параметр skills не будет передан

Comment: очень полезная статья, спасибо. вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var Person = {
 constructor: function(name, age, gender) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  return this; // A: Что тут возвращает this? Все аргументы из фунцкии или что?
                             // Q: Зависит от метода вызова.
                             //   Метод: Person
                             //   Функция: window (или undefined в строгом режиме)
 },
};

/*________________________*/


var WebDeveloper = Object.create(Person); //Тут пока всё более-менее понятно
WebDeveloper.constructor = function(name, age, gender, skills) {
 Person.constructor.apply(this, arguments); // A: что делает apply? я читал, что устанавливает значение this в функции. Отсюда и вопрос: разве this это типо не ключевое слово а-ля var? 
                                                   // Q: Действительно, вызывает с указанным this. Здесь передаётся текущий this
 this.skills = skills || []; // A: что собственно тут устанавливается? skills или массив? пустой? и когда сработает skills, а когда массив? значение skills внутри функции теперь становится и значением skills которая за пределами функции - это я понял. ну а метод apply тут причем?
                                    // Q: Устанавливается свойство равное или skills, либо, если он false, пустой массив
                                    // apply вызывает родительский конструктор, чтобы он навесил свои значения (паттерн такой есть)
 return this;
};

var developer = Object.create(WebDeveloper).constructor("Jack", 21, "male", ["html", "css", "js", "php", "mysql"]);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное =)

Comment: @ebaklak, Пожалуйста :)

Comment: _Конструктор: Person_ - это как?:)

Comment: Имелось ввиду классы. Тут не класс, но если бы был бы... :)

Comment: @Other, если метод используется как конструктор `this` - это всегда создаваемый объект, а у тебя получилось, что это существующий

Comment: @Grundy, давайте я просто уберу упоминание о классах? Я не указывал какой именно -- создаваемый или существующий -- будет объект.

Comment: @Other, у тебя было написано `Person`, что совпадает с ранее объявленной переменной :)

Comment: @Grundy, какие Ваши доказательства? Внутри всё равно был бы экземпляр от `Person`. Не сам `Person`, конечно.

Comment: Также можно упомянуть, что возврат из конструктора определяет фабрику, заменяет создаваемый объект. Возврат this таким образом можно опустить.