# Как присвоить функцию в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Можно ли присвоить переменной функцию (а не результат ее выполнения)? Например, если нужно несколько одинаковых функций с разным именем? Или нужно создать новую функцию, которая будет содержать функционал уже существующей.

Comment: присвоение функции ничем не отличается от присвоения любого другого значения

Comment: если функции должны быть одинаковыми, почему у них должно быть разное название?

Comment: Вы правы, я при присваивании машинально писал () после названия, нужно быть внимательнее,вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: Например чтобы писать НазваниеФункции() а не НазваниеОбъекта.НазваниеПодобъекта.НазваниеФункции()

Comment: обрати внимание, что в этом случае можешь столкнуться с [потерей контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020/186999)

Answer (score 0):

```
let func = function FucnName () {};
```

Comment: попробуй писать более развернутые ответы, а не просто кусок непонятного кода

Comment: хорошо, просто этот код совсем простенький

Comment: Есть сомнения касательно `Сами функции — нельзя`. Просьба исправить и добавить пример кода, если это не так.

Comment: @Arhad, на самом деле конечно можно

Comment: @Arhad почему мой ответ изменен, на: сами функции - нельзя. Поясните пожалуйста

Comment: @АлександрПиткевич, вы привели только пример с лямбдами, вот и сложилось впечатление, что только с ними и можно. Убрал спорную часть.

Comment: @Arhad обычную функцию Function Declaration тоже можно присваивать

Comment: @Arhad не стоит полностью переписывать чужие ответы.

Comment: @PashaPash, понял.

Comment: @Arhad я переоткрыл вопрос (т.к. вопрос сам по себе вполне хороший, вне зависимости от причин, которые побудили автора его задать) - так что можете запостить новый ответ :)

Comment: @PashaPash, уже было несколько вопросов, про забывание/лишнее выставление круглых скобок, а присваивание функции ничем не отличается от присваиванию любой другой переменной. Поэтому не стоило переоткрывать, тем более когда в ответе нет никакого объяснения.

Comment: @Grundy этот вопрос однозначно не про забытые круглые скобки. Проблема в том, что пока вопрос закрыт - к нему не появится новый ответ с объяснением (разве только кто-то полностью перепишет чужой ответ, как сделал выше Arhad). "присваивание функции ничем не отличается от присваиванию любой другой переменной" - запостите это как ответ с примером в одну строку и будет win.