# обращение к переменным объекта JavaScript

Tags: javascript

скажите почему след код не выводит измененое имя и возраст?

```js
 var person = (function (name, age) {
     var
         $name = name,
         $age = age;
     
     return {
         name: $name,
         age: $age,
         setName: function (name) { $name = name;},
         setAge: function (age) { $age = age;}
     };
       
})('Gregory', 42); 
     
person.setName('Miller');
person.setAge(30);
     
console.log(person.name);
console.log(person.age);
```

Выхлоп:

```
Gregory
42
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что сеттеры меняют локальные переменные, которые дальше нигде не получаются.

Значения полей *name* и *age* устанавливаются один раз и затем не изменяются.

Для исправления, вместо полей можно использовать геттеры

```js
var person = (function(name, age) {  
  var   $name = name,
        $age = age;   
  return {  
    get name() {
      return $name
    },
      get age() {
      return $age
    },
       setName: function(name) {
      $name = name;
    },
        setAge: function(age) {
      $age = age;
    }  
  }; 
})('Gregory', 42); 
person.setName('Miller');
person.setAge(30); 
console.log(person.name);
console.log(person.age);
```

Либо менять непосредственно поля объекта

```js
var person = (function(name, age) {  
  return {  
    name: name,
    age: age,
    setName: function(name) {
      this.name = name;
    },
    setAge: function(age) {
      this.age = age;
    }  
  }; 
})('Gregory', 42); 
person.setName('Miller');
person.setAge(30); 
console.log(person.name);
console.log(person.age);
```

но в этом случае стоит следить за возможной [потерей контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020/186999)

Comment: т.е. как я понял то что возвращается в name и age это и есть поля person? а не $name, $age?

Comment: @Cfon, именно, твоя функция вернула объект, инициализировав его поля и, по сути, на этом все закончилось

Comment: А все понял! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решение через класс, на мой взгляд, нагляднее и большая возможность есть к расширению

```
class Person {
    constructor (name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    };
    setName (name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
    setAge (age) {
        this.age = age;
    };
}
let person = new Person ('Gregory', 42);
person.setName('Miller');
person.setAge(30);
console.log(person.name);
console.log(person.age);
```

Comment: не уверен, что это в стиле JavaScript ;) и будет ли это работать везде?

Comment: Это решение соответствует ES6 :) Все современные браузеры поддерживают этот стандарт)

Comment: я сам плюсовик, но недавно подсел на JavaScript, именно из-за не стандартного подхода в объектам ;)

Comment: @Cfon мое решение выше демонстрирует ООП в прототипном стиле с использованием нового стандарта, но ведь согласитесь, решение выглядит проще?)

Comment: спасибо, просто я изучаю JavaScript по книжке "Разработка одностраничных веб-приложений. М.Миковски, Дж.Пауэлл, 2014" там про это не пишется :)

Comment: @Cfon на момент написания этой книги про это и не знал никто, я полагаю) уверен там переменные еще через var обозначают)

Comment: всетаки пока буду придерживаться стиля var :)

Comment: @Cfon as you wish)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var person = (function (name, age) {
     var
         $name = name,
         $age = age;
     
     return {
         name: $name,
         age: $age,
         setName: function (name) { this.name = name;},
         setAge: function (age) { this.age = age;}
     };
       
})('Gregory', 42); 
     
person.setName('Miller');
person.setAge(30);
     
console.log(person.name);
console.log(person.age);
```

Comment: оригинально ;))

Comment: моя ошибка была в том что я мыслил как С++ программист, как я потом понял оператор return возвращает объект со своими атрибутами и функциями, я же думал что в атрибутах передаются ссылки на переменные функции $name и $age.