# Правильное написание плагина на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Возник вопрос о правильном подходе создания плагина на js.

Пример работы на [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WlMB3nhKPNPuWGHoExGV?p=preview), а так же код на [github](https://github.com/webslavik/popup-gallery/tree/dev).

Суть работы плагина:

- на странице есть изображения, при клике на которые открывается модальное окно;
- в этом модальном окне есть **Слайдер** и **Превьюшки** с этими изображениями, которые мы можем листать, переключить и т.д.;
- в слайдер можем передать параметры отображение кол-ва превью и возможность их отключить;
- на одной странице можем использовать плагин несколько раз.

**Проблема**: когда используется два и более раз, то плагин ломается и отображет только последнюю галерею.

```
(function() {
  let gallery_1 = new SkySlider('.first-gallery');

  let gallery_2 = new SkySlider('#second-gallery', {
    showThumbnails: true,
    thumbnailsItemCount: 6,
  });
})();
```

Comment: потому что надо разобраться как работает `this`, а не пытаться костылить с одной локальной переменной на все экземпляры

Comment: У вас `_` "глобальна" для всех слайдеров, поэтому при создании нового слайдера, у всех старых ссылка в `_` меняется на `this` нового слайдера (все из-за замыкания)

Comment: Почему бы не сделать остальные функции методами `SkySlider`?

Comment: @ThisMan большое спасибо!

Comment: @ThisMan, оформи ответом :-)

Comment: Оформил, как ответ

Comment: Подробнее о [потере и сохранении контекста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020/186999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо хранения `this` в замыкании, как это сделано у вас

```
(function() {
    // for `this`
    let _;

    function SkySlider(selector = null, options = null) {
        _ = this;
    }

    // остальные функции использующие _ в качестве this
})()
```

Можно все вспомогательные функции поместить в прототип функции `SkySlider`

```
(function() {
    function SkySlider(selector = null, options = null) {}

    SkySlider.prototype.init = function () {}
    SkySlider.prototype.otherMethod = function () {}

    // либо по другому делаем функцию доступной из вне
    window.SkySlider = SkySlider
})()
```

В таких методах `this` будет ссылать на текущий экземпляр класса и не перезаписывать какую-то глобальную переменную

Comment: плохой пример с прототипами :-) _SkySlider_ будет виден _только_ внутри этой IIFE

Comment: @Grundy, у него же ниже в коде есть строка `window.SkySlider = SkySlider`

Comment: Ага, а у тебя не было :)

Comment: @Grundy, просто это не совсем относится к вопросу, я и подумал, что вставлять остальной код не обязательно)