# Передача контекста в метода класса

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, reactjs, typescript

Существует реакт-компонент и класс с обработчиками этого компонента, который строится на специальном абстрактном классе. Выглядит это так:

**Абстрактный класс**

```
export default abstract class HandlersCreator<C extends Component> {
    constructor(public component: C) {}

    protected get props(): C['props'] {
        return this.component.props
    }

    protected get state(): C['state'] {
        return this.component.state
    }

    protected setState<K extends keyof C['state']>(
        state: Pick<C['state'], K>,
        callback?: () => any
    ): void {
        return this.component.setState(state, callback)
    }

    protected dispatch<A extends Action>(action: A): A {
        const dispatchFunc: Dispatch<C> = (<any>this.component.props).dispatch
        return dispatchFunc(action)
    }
}
```

**Класс с обработчиками**

```
export default class Handlers extends HandlersCreator<MyComponent> {
    public onClick() {
        this.setState({ property: value })
    }
}
```

**Компонент**

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.handlers = new Handlers(this)
    }

    public render() {
        return <div onClick={this.handlers.onClick}/>
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что контекст (this) передаётся в метод «onClick» не от экземпляра класса Handlers, а от div'а, соответственно такой код выдаст исключение, мол this.setState is not a function.

Каким образом можно предустановить контекст без прямого бинда внутри onClick'а div'а? Спасибо.

**UPD**
В голове появляется мысль пробежаться в конструкторе абстрактного класса по методам экземпляра и пробиндить их все на this, но не знаю как это делать.

Comment: В дубликате указаны способы сохранения контекста, и причины почему он меняется. Так что вполне дубликат

Comment: @Grundy, ни одного ответа там не приведено, относящихся к этому вопросу. И повторюсь — сохранение контекста это не цель данного вопроса. Вопрос состоит в предопределении контекста методов. Прочитайте последнее предложение в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @Grundy и ежели я ошибаюсь, будьте добры, объясните, как же применять ответы из того вопроса к моему с приведением примеров

Comment: Какие-то недомиксины...

Comment: _И повторюсь — сохранение контекста это не цель данного вопроса. Вопрос состоит в предопределении контекста методов._ - ты как раз и говоришь о сохранении контекста, чтобы контекст внутри onClick всегда был на объект, а не на элемент. И там для этого приведено как минимум два решения: bind и стрелочные функции

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо городить какие-то мутные полумиксины. Если уж есть необходимость вынесения хэндлеров в отдельный класс (переиспользование хэндлеров?), то надо, чтобы эти хэндлеры работали непосредственно с компонентом, а не выволакивали из него какие-то куски:

```js
class HandlersCreator {
  constructor(component) {
    this.component = component

    for (var p=this; (p=Object.getPrototypeOf(p))!==Object.prototype; ) {
      for (var key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p)) {
        if (key !== 'constructor' && typeof p[key] === 'function') {
          this[key] = this[key].bind(this)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class Handlers extends HandlersCreator {
  onClick() {
    var {state} = this.component
  
    this.component.setState({
      count: state.count + 1
    })
  }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { count: 0 }
    this.handlers = new Handlers(this)
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handlers.onClick}>{this.state.count}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.querySelector('main'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

PS: От тайпскрипта избавился, поскольку на ответ он не влияет, а без него можно запускаемый сниппет сделать.

Comment: Мутный полумиксин нужен что бы избежать длинных конструкций вроде «this.component.setState». Спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz, в принципе, этот код совместим со свойствами, которые были в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Пока использую вложенные функции для обработчиков событий элементов, но это не самое красивое решение

```
export default class Handlers extends HandlersCreator<MyComponent> {
    public onClick(): eventHandler {
        return (event: Event) => {
            this.setState({ property: value })
        }
    }
}

// ...

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.handlers = new Handlers(this)
    }

    public render() {
        return <div onClick={this.handlers.onClick()}/>
    }
}
```

**З.Ы.**
Спасибо сообществу stackoverflow, что восстановили справедливость и переоткрыли вопрос

Comment: ну то есть как и в дубликате: стрелочная функция, либо bind.

Comment: Плохое решение, т. к. создаётся уйма лишних функций.

Comment: @Grundy ну то есть это не то решение, которое мне надо, всё верно

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz все-таки гляньте тот вопрос, дубликатом которого является ваш. Я там как раз новый ответ написал, который подходит как раз для TypeScript и обработчиков событий.