# Добавление класса силами jQuery среди аналогичных тегов

Tags: jquery

Требуется среди сотни тэгов "а" найти нужный с классом selected и добавть ему еще один класс.

```js
if($('a').hasClass('selected')){
    $(this).addClass('red');
}
```

```css
.red{color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="selected">One</a>
```

Чего-то не то...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: @Grundy я не нашел ответа на свой вопрос

Comment: Там описано как определяется чему равен `this`. Посмотри чему он равен в твоем случае

Comment: Вообще, тебе и условие это не нужно. Ты хочешь элементам с классом `selected` добавить еще один класс. Вот и выбери сначала нужные элементы, а затем добавь им класс: `$('a.selected').addClass('red')`

Comment: при переключении табов меняется класс в активном окне на selected. Вот и не знаю как подступиться, чтобы при переключении табов менялся цвет фона активной вкладки

Comment: решил, спасибо за комментарии

Comment: @Proshka лучше бы добавлять второй класс в том же месте, где добавляется и `active`, дабы не перебирать эти сотни тегов каждый раз

Comment: @webDev_, зачем, если уже есть `active`?

Comment: @Grundy тоже так подумал. но раз вопрос в этом, так по нему и помогаю. как заметил автор это делает для того что бы не дублировать часто используемые стили во всех классах