# Как получить контекст объекта в котором находится объект? JS

Tags: javascript

Есть код такого плана:

```js
var objParent = {

  text: 'Нужное значение',
  
  objChild: {
  
    context: this,
    context1: objParent,
    text: 'Ненужное значение',
    
    needHere: function(){
    
      console.log(this.text);
      console.log(this.context.text);
      console.log(this.context1.text);
      
      // Ниодин из вариантов не дает нужного значения
      
    },
  },
}

objParent.objChild.needHere()
```

Надо получить значение из объекта родителя, находясь в объекте дитя. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: можно сделать так: `console.log(objParent.objChild.text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию-конструктор для создания объекта.

```js
function CreateObject() {

  var objParent = {
    text: 'текст',

    objChild: {
      needHere: function() {
        console.log(this.context.text);
      }
    }
  };

  /* присваиваем, определяем контекст в необходимое место */
  objParent.objChild.context = objParent; 

  return objParent;
}

var objParent = CreateObject();
objParent.objChild.needHere();
```

Comment: если убрать функцию - ничего не изменится

Comment: @Grundy да, но её можно использовать многократно, для этого её и сделал

Comment: @Grundy хочется что бы за конструкцию объекта отвечала одна функция или одно выражение, по моему восприятию красоты кода, если нужно два выражения, это на мой взгляд не так красиво, и к тому же может быть что кто-то создаст скажем первым выражением, а второе забудет, с этой точки зрения делал.

Comment: @Grundy то есть, если точек создания объекта в приложении может быть несколько, тогда работает принцип DRY, и не только он. Если объект создаётся только в одном месте, то можно и без функции думаю.

Answer (score 1):

Единственный способ в литерале объекта обратиться к нему же с помощью `this` - это использовать функцию, либо более удобную запись - getter. (подробнее про определение `this` в вопросе [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/186999))

При этом доступ будет только к самому объекту, но не к родителю (на самом деле тут имеется ввиду контейнер).

Для доступа к родителю необходимо указать ссылку на него напрямую

```js
var objParent = {

  text: 'Нужное значение',

  objChild: {

    get context() {
      return this; // вернет objChild
    },
    get context1() {
      return objParent; // вернет значение переменной objParent на момент вызова
    },
    text: 'Ненужное значение',

    needHere: function() {

      console.log(this.text);
      console.log(this.context.text);
      console.log(this.context1.text); // нужное значение

    },
  },
}

objParent.objChild.needHere()
```