# Вопрос React js специалистам, почему не срабатывает window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.getMouse)?

Tags: reactjs

Нажмите на зеленый квадратик. Можно перетаскивать его по экрану, но при отжатии мышки действие не отвязывается, не подскажите почему?

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  let deltaX;
  let deltaY;
  this.getMouse = this.getMouse.bind(this);
  this.state = {
   divStyle: {
    width:"1000px",
    height: "500px",
    outline: "1px solid red",
    position:"relative"
   },
   move: {
    width:"200px",
    height:"100px",
    outline: "1px solid green",
    position:"absolute"

   }
  }

 }

  getMouse(e){
            var pX = e.pageX;
            var pY = e.pageY;
      this.ourdiv.style.left = (pX - this.deltaX) + "px";
      this.ourdiv.style.top = (pY - this.deltaY) + "px";
   

        }


  MouseDown(e){
    var mousePosX = e.pageX;
                var mousePosY = e.pageY;
                var divPosX = this.ourdiv.offsetLeft;
                var divPosY = this.ourdiv.offsetTop;
                this.deltaX = mousePosX - divPosX;
                this.deltaY = mousePosY - divPosY;
                window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.getMouse);
                this.ourdiv.onmouseup = function() {
                    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.getMouse);
                }
  }
 

 render() {

  return( 
   <div>
    <div style={this.state.divStyle}>
     <div style={this.state.move} ref={(ourdiv) => this.ourdiv = ourdiv} onMouseDown ={this.MouseDown.bind(this)}></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   )

 }
}





ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в [потере контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/178988).
Добавляешь ты нормальный обработчик, а удаляешь `undefined`:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getMouse = this.getMouse.bind(this);
    this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this);
  }

  getMouse(e) {
    var pX = e.pageX;
    var pY = e.pageY;
    this.inner.style.left = (pX - this.deltaX) + "px";
    this.inner.style.top = (pY - this.deltaY) + "px";
  }

  onMouseDown(e) {
    var mousePosX = e.pageX;
    var mousePosY = e.pageY;
    var divPosX = this.inner.offsetLeft;
    var divPosY = this.inner.offsetTop;
    this.deltaX = mousePosX - divPosX;
    this.deltaY = mousePosY - divPosY;
    console.log('add', typeof this.getMouse), window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.getMouse);
    this.inner.onmouseup = function() {
      console.log('remove', typeof this.getMouse), window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.getMouse);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="outer">
        <div className="inner"
             ref={inner => this.inner = inner}
             onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Но у кода есть и ещё один потенциальный косяк: я не уверен, что гарантируется нахождение мыши над внутренним div'ом и вызов события `onmouseup`.

Comment: Я запустил ваш код, он также работает

Comment: @Sinevik, мой код работает так же как твой, просто добавлен вывод на консоль. А как исправить написано по ссылке. Простейший вариант - заменить `this.inner.onmouseup = function() {` на `this.inner.onmouseup =
 () => {`, но лучше всё-таки прочитать информацию по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdOapX?editors=0010
Не смешивайте React и работу с DOM напрямую, это плохой подход. В данном случае DOM нужен только для вычисления deltaX, deltaY.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handlerMouseMove = this.handlerMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.handlerMouseUp = this.handlerMouseUp.bind(this);
    this.handlerMouseDown = this.handlerMouseDown.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        divStyle: {
            width:"1000px",
            height: "500px",
            outline: "1px solid red",
            position:"relative"
        },
        move: {
            width:"200px",
            height:"100px",
            outline: "1px solid green",
            position:"absolute"
        }
    }

}


    handlerMouseDown(e)
    {
        this.deltaX = e.pageX - this.ourdiv.offsetLeft;
        this.deltaY = e.pageY - this.ourdiv.offsetTop;
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handlerMouseMove);
    }
    handlerMouseUp(e)
    {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handlerMouseMove);
    }
    handlerMouseMove(e)
    {
        this.setState({ move: {
            ...this.state.move,
            left: e.pageX - this.deltaX,
            top: e.pageY - this.deltaY
        } });
    }


render() {

    return( 
        <div>
            <div style={this.state.divStyle}>
                <div
                    ref={ourdiv => this.ourdiv = ourdiv}
                    style={this.state.move}
                    onMouseDown={this.handlerMouseDown}
                    onMouseUp={this.handlerMouseUp}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        )

}
```

}

Comment: На codepan все мигает, ничего не понятно