# Вызвать функцию внутри ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular5

Использую Angular 5(до этого с ангуляром не работал) не могу обратиться к функции которая находится внутри ngOninit
объясните пожалуйста как это сделать. вот мой пример

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
objDate = Date.now();
slide1 = 'test text';


ngOnInit() {
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.substrate .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 5000);

function nextSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function previousSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

function goToSlide(n) {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}

function next() {
  alert('YoY');
  nextSlide();
};
function previous() {
  alert('YoY1');
  previousSlide();
}
}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="block-btn-name">
    <div (click)="next()" class="btn btn-left"></div>
  <h1 class="slide-name">{{slide1}}</h1>
    <div (click)="previous()" class="btn btn-right"></div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вынести всё это из ngOnInit, зачем оно там вообще?

Comment: Потому что вне ngOnInit я даже не могу присвоить DOM            
 slides = document.querySelectorAll('.substrate .slide'); Так как он еще не создан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы функция могла использоваться в шаблоне, она должна быть методом соответствующего компонента.

Следовательно нужно сделать методами все нужные функции, например:

```
ngOnInit(){...}

goToSlide(n) {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
```

Для того, чтобы вызвать один метод из другого, нужно использовать ключевое слово `this`:

```
nextSlide() {
  this.goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}
```

---

После переделки на методы перестанет работать `setInterval(nextSlide, 5000)` из-за потере контекста (подробнее в вопросе [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/186999))

А также все переменные определенные в ngOnInit и используемые в методах, должны стать полями класса, и обращение к ним также будет через `this`.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, попробовал вынести за ngOnInit(){...} Теперь стало совсем все плохо так как даже не могу присвоить NodeList переменной по всей видимости на момент присваивания этого DOM еще нет или он пустой это как нибудь можно обыграть? slides = document.querySelectorAll('.substrate .slide');

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛюбимов, это надо вообще убрать. Посмотреть справку по Ангуляру и полностью переделать