# React.js изменение state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Не могу разобраться с работой setState() у React.js. При обработке события выбрасывает ошибку `setState is not a function`
Привожу пример кода. Работаю с версией 16.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: 'nothing'
        }
    }

    changeText() {
        this.setState({
            message: 'new text'
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'container'}>
                <h2 onClick={this.changeText}>Click me!</h2>
                <p>{this.state.message}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что форма объявления функции `changeText() {...` теряет контекст. Нужно либо использовать **arrow function** - `changeText = () => {...`, либо привязывать контекст к функции в вызове `{this.changeText.bind(this)}`

Comment: Спасибо, со стрелочной функцией работает. Буду разбираться.