# ReactJS ошибка при вызове setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент на реакте, который описывает одно задание в Todo-приложении. Задание представляется элементом `<li>`, в котором есть текст и кнопка удаления в виде `<span>`. Если кликнуть по `<li>`, текст должен зачеркиваться. Если кликнуть по `<span>` с крестиком, запись удаляется.

```
import React from "react";

class TodoItem extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: props.item, done: false };
    }

    render()
    {
        let style = this.state.done ? "done" : "";
        return (
            <li onClick={this.handleComplete} className={style}>
                {this.state.text}
                <span className="close" onClick={this.handleRemove}>{"\u00D7"}</span>
            </li>
        );
    }

    handleComplete()
    {
        this.setState({ done: true });
    }

    handleRemove()
    {
        alert("remove");
    }
};

export default TodoItem;
```

При вызове обработчика `handleComplete()` вываливается ошибка в окне браузера с указанием на строку, где обновляется состояние компонента. Из-за чего возникает эта ошибка?

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: this is undefined
handleComplete
src/TodoItem.js:24
```

Место, где используется компонент:

```
import React from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

const List = props => {
    return (
    <ul>
        {
            props.items.map((item, index) => <TodoItem item={item} />)
        }
    </ul>);
};

export default List;
```

Comment: А текст ошибки?

Comment: @bonusrk, TypeError: this is undefined
handleComplete
src/TodoItem.js:24

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: И вот еще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/820533/178779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

handleComplete() теряет контекст. Нужно либо объявить метод как стрелочную функцию

```
handleComplete = () => {}
```

либо в конструкторе привязать контекст

```
this.handleComplete = this.handleComplete.bind(this)
```

Comment: Почему функция теряет свой контекст?

Comment: Простите, не теряет, она просто имеет другой контекст, в её "this" метод setState не объявлен. Нужно явно указать какой контекст использовать