# jquery получение this

Tags: jquery

Доброе время суток. Не могу получить по `this`  ссылку на объект. Что то я совсем плох стал :) Может пора отдохнуть, где ошибка? 
Не могу понять, раньше то работало, где буксую?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', 'li', (e) => {
    let msg = 'this = ' + this + ' или ' + $(this);
    console.log(msg);
    $('#result').text(msg);
  });

});
```

```css
li{
  list-style:  none;
  padding: 1rem
  }
li:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: skyblue
}

p{
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li id="2">2</li>
    <li id="3">3</li>
    <li id="4">4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<p id="result"></p>
```

`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте стрелочную функцию, если Вам важен контекст ее вызова.

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  let msg = 'this = ' + this + ' или ' + $(this);
  console.log(msg);
  $('#result').text(msg);
});
```

Comment: Хм... все верно, что то я не понял с es6 нужно перечитать, решил перейти да видимо не удачно. Спасибо. Ответ приму как спадет лимит.