# Вывзов метода внутри Ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите, как правильно отдать результат запроса в метод конструктора?
И почему нельзя просто вызвать метод конструктора внутри ajax?
Пытаюсь делать вот так, не получается, пишет что `process is not a function`

```
    var ReviewBox = function(){
        this.reviews = [1,2,3];
        this.request();
        this.render();
        this.process();

}
ReviewBox.prototype.request = function(data){
    $.get({
        url: 'json/reviews.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response) 

            console.log(this.reviews); //здесь почему то не вызывает

            this.process(response); //и здесь не передает
        }
    })
}
ReviewBox.prototype.process = function(response){
         console.log(response)
}
ReviewBox.prototype.render = function(response){
//        console.log('123');
}
```

P/S в ответе получаю массив, пытаюсь передать результат в process или обработать в render.

Comment: [Доступ к объекту из внутреннего метода](http://learn.javascript.ru/internal-external-interface#%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3-4-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: У вас this отклеился

Comment: ReviewBox.prototype.process = function(){
        this.request();
}
такой способ не возвращает мне результат, а лишь вызывает метод из метода

Comment: request действительно ничего не возвращает - там нет return. уверен, что вам сейчас будет полезнее не задавать вопросы, а прочесть базовую документацию

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Благодарен за ссылки на документацию, ответ я нашел в туториале jQuery, где описано сохранение контекста при передаче this в запрос,
достаточно было просто указать контекст

```
 context: this,
        success: function(response){
           this.process(response)
        }
```

Далее можно вызывать результат в другом методе

```
ReviewBox.prototype.process = function(response){
    console.log(response)
}
```

Comment: завязывал бы ты с jquery. библиотека хорошая, но ты даже js пытаешься понять сквозь призму туториалов по jquery