# Async snotify axios in vuejs project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios

Пытаюсь разобраться с [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), обёрнутым в [snotify](https://github.com/artemsky/vue-snotify) в своём проекте на [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/). Нашёл [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47682783/6004176) того, как можно поместить одно в другое, но возникает проблема - как в случае успеха или ошибки выполнить тот или иной код. Ведь внутри `Promise` и внутри `axios` я не могу обратиться ко внешним функциям `vue`. Как быть?

Ниже код запроса `axios` к api `axios.post('samples',this.sample)` перед этим обернутый в `Promise` для того, чтобы `snotify` (показывает сообщения пользователяю) во время выполнения запроса анимировал сообщение, что идёт запрос. Когда запрос завершён успешно, внутри `axios` вызывается `resolve` - отображается сообщение об успехе. Если ошибка, то она отлавливается и выводится сообщение, описанное в  `reject`.

Мне же нужно не просто показать сообщение об успехе или ошибке пользователю, мне помимо всего прочего нужно произвести кое-какие действия в том и другом случае. Например, если запрос состоялся, то выводится сообщение об успехе и вызывается функция `this.test();` Однако я получаю ошибку - функция не вызывается.

```
<template>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="createSample">
        Добавить образец
    </button>      
</template>
```

Скрипт:

```
  export default {
    name: "sample",
    data() { return { sample: {} } },
    methods: {
      test() {
        console.log('it works!');
      },
      createSample() {
        this.$snotify.async('Called with promise', 'Success async', () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return axios.post('samples', this.sample)
              .then(function(success) {
                success = success.data;
                console.log(success); //Ответ сервера отображается. В БД данные есть.
                this.test(); //Ошибка. Не может выполнить функцию. Вызывается reject
                resolve({
                  title: 'Успех',
                  body: 'Новый образец добавлен',
                  config: { closeOnClick: true }
                });
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                reject({
                  title: 'Ошибка',
                  body: 'Что-то пошло не так',
                  config: { closeOnClick: true }
                })
              });
          });
        });
      },
    }
  }
```

**Рабочий пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qckr5t2v/) прилагается.**

Comment: Лично я не совсем понял, что не так. Можете более детально описать, какой код выполнить и где? Думаю, это поможет хотя бы понимать вопрос.

Comment: @DenisBubnov Обновил вопрос. Добавил рабочий пример проблемы на fiddle

Comment: Скажите, почему вы в одном месте написали `(resolve, reject) => {`, а в другом - `function(success) {`?

Comment: Кстати, зачем вы создаете новый Promise, если методы then и catch и так возвращают Promise?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: @PavelMayorov потому что это один из примеров в документации - https://artemsky.github.io/vue-snotify/documentation/essentials/examples.html раздел Async

Comment: @n.osennij отличие вашего случая от примера в документации заключается в том, что вы не вызываете setTimeout.

Comment: @PavelMayorov и как оно тогда будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто нужно пробросить `this` внутрь функции промиса. Ваш HTML остается без изменений, таким как и был ранее:

```
<div id="app">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="createSample">
            Добавить образец
        </button>   
   <vue-snotify></vue-snotify>
</div>
```

Вот JS немного поменяется (за основу взят ваш код из [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qckr5t2v/)):

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log('it works!');
    },
    createSample() {
      this.$snotify.async('Called with promise', 'Success async', () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(function(success) {
              success = success.data;
              console.log(success); // Ответ сервера
              this.test(); // После того, как сделали bind(this) - ошибки не будет
              resolve({
                title: 'Успех',
                body: 'Новый образец добавлен',
                config: {
                  closeOnClick: true
                }
              });
            }.bind(this)) // вот тут мы пробросили this внутрь
            .catch(function(error) {
              reject({
                title: 'Ошибка',
                body: 'Что-то пошло не так',
                config: {
                  closeOnClick: true
                }
              })
            });
        });
      });
    },
  }
});
```

Все решилось с помощью добавления `.bind(this)` к функции, которая выполняется внутри `then`. Если не выполнить `bind`, то `this` внутри функции - это всего лишь область функции.

---

Также, есть еще более простой вариант - это стрелочная функция. Стрелочные функции при создании привязываются к текущему значению `this`. Поэтому код станет немного *современнее* и проще (на примере `then`, где вызывается функция `test`):

```
.then((success) => {
    success = success.data;
    console.log(success); // Ответ сервера 
    this.test(); // Можем выполнить эту функцию
    resolve({
        title: 'Успех',
        body: 'Новый образец добавлен',
        config: {
            closeOnClick: true
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: А не лучше ли стрелочную функцию использовать вместо bind?

Comment: @PavelMayorov хм... а вот как-то не пришло в голову сразу... дополню ответ и этим вариантом, он покрасивше и проще будет.