# JS ошибка вызова функции из другой функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код: При вызове функции `setCenter` из `calcMinMax` я получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.setCenter is not a function at
>   PanZoom.calcMinMax

Что можете подсказать? В чем ошибка?

```
function PanZoom(id){
    $el = $(id);
    var minZoom;
    var maxZoom;
    var currentZoom;
    this.setCenter = function(){
        var cW = $(window).width()/2 - ($el.outerWidth(true)/2);
        var cH = $(window).height()/2 - ($el.outerWidth(true)/2);
        this.panzoom(cW, cH, this.minZoom); // это работает
    };
    this.calcMinMax = function(){
        if($(window).width() < $(window).height()){
            this.minZoom = parseFloat(($(window).width() / ($el.outerWidth(true))).toFixed(4));
        }else{
            this.minZoom = parseFloat(($(window).height() / ($el.outerHeight(true))).toFixed(4));
        }
        this.currentZoom = this.minZoom;
        this.maxZoom = parseFloat((this.minZoom + 2).toFixed(4));

        if(this.currentZoom == this.minZoom) this.setCenter(1);  // это не работает
    };

    $(window).resize( this.calcMinMax );
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `this.calcMinMax` в качестве обработчика события `resize` будет вызываться в контексте `window`. Чтобы обеспечить правильный контекст, нужно:

```
$(window).resize( this.calcMinMax.bind(this) );
```

или

```
$(window).resize(() => this.calcMinMax());
```

---

Зачем вот это?

```
var minZoom;
var maxZoom;
var currentZoom;
```

Имелось в виду вот это?

```
this.minZoom = 0;
this.maxZoom = 0;
this.currentZoom = 0;
```

Какой смысл проверки?

```
if(this.currentZoom == this.minZoom)
```

если двумя строчками выше

```
this.currentZoom = this.minZoom;
```

Answer (score 0):

у каждой функции своя область видимости this. Сделайте так:

```
function PanZoom(id){
    ...
    var _this = this;
    this.setCenter = function(){
        ...
        _this.panzoom(cW, cH, this.minZoom); // это работает
    };
    this.calcMinMax = function(){
        ...    
        if(_this.currentZoom == _this.minZoom) _this.setCenter(1);
    };

    $(window).resize( this.calcMinMax );
}
```

заодно проверьте и другие this во вложенных функциях

Comment: это не "область видимости", a "контекст вызова"