# Как выглядит изнутри нативная функция apply?

Tags: javascript, функции, методы

Как известно синтаксис функции apply: `func.apply(context, [arg1, arg2]);`
Как будет выглядеть кастомная функция, которая принимает контекст,  аргументы в массиве и передает ее в другую функцию?

Comment: вопрос о полифиле или о нативной реализации в конкретном движке?

Answer (score 1):

Для установки *контекста* есть [несколько способов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020/186999).

Например можно воспользоваться методом [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

В этом случае реализация может быть следующей:

```js
function apply2(func, context, args) { // функция принимает саму функцию, новый контекст, и массив параметров, которые необходимые передать 
  var wrapper = func.bind(context); // привязываем контекст
  return wrapper(...args); // выполняем с привязанным параметром и переданными аргументами
}

function test(a, b) {
  return this.a + a + b;
}

console.log(apply2(test, {
  a: 1
}, [2, 3]));
```