# Как использовать свойства внутри объекта?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Я пытаюсь использовать `foo` и `bar` внутри создаваемого config файла, но получаю ошибку:

> ReferenceError: foo is not defined

Пример кода:

```
module.exports = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  array: [foo, bar]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  array: function() { return [this.foo, this.bar]; }
}
```

Comment: В данном случае выдаёт ошибку `TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined` при попытке получить данные.

Comment: @Arnokay, видимо, Вы [потеряли контекст вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/176064). Как Вы обращаетесь к методу `array`? Можно дописать `.bind(exports)` к функции(если сделать какую-никакую ссылку заранее)..

Answer (score 0):

Использовать свойства объекта при его создании не получится.
Т.к. у вас там не JSON, а полноценный js код, можете использовать обычные переменные:

```
let foo = 'foo';
let bar = 'bar';
module.exports = {
  foo, // эквивалентно записи foo:foo
  bar,
  array: [foo, bar]
};
```

Однако, при таком подходе значения всё ещё никак не связаны друг с другом - их можно менять независимо...

---

Можно использовать Proxy, чтобы реализовать подобное динамическое свойство.

```js
let foo = 'foo'; 
let bar = 'bar'; 

const cfg = {foo, bar};

let config = new Proxy(cfg, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (prop === 'array') return Object.values(target);
    return target[prop];
  },
  set(target, prop, value) {
    if (prop === 'array') throw new Error('array is read-only');
    target[prop] = value;
    return true;
  }
});
// module exports = config;
console.log(config.foo, config.array);
config.foo = 'updated foo';
console.log(config.foo, config.array);
```