# Почему не работает self = this таким образом?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю пример с ***learn.javascript***    [эту задачу  plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CNryDR58MdGL4y2W0U7L?p=preview) - в коде по ссылке уже рабочее решение, но не понимаю почему именно так нужно?

И не понимаю почему вот так вот `self` не работает?

Контекст ведь должен передаваться по идее. Почему обязательно там нужно обертку делать?

```js
"use strict";

function ask(question, answer, ok, fail) {
  var result = prompt(question, '');
  if (result.toLowerCase() == answer.toLowerCase()) ok();
  else fail();
}

var user = {
  login: 'Василий',
  password: '12345',

  loginOk: function() {
    alert(this.login + ' вошёл в сайт');
  },

  loginFail: function() {
    alert(this.login + ': ошибка входа');
  },

  checkPassword: function() {
    var self = this;
    ask("Ваш пароль?", self.password, self.loginOk, self.loginFail);
  }
};

user.checkPassword();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что интерпретатор понимает вашу программу вот так:

```
checkPassword: function() {
  var self = this;
  var temp1 = self.password;
  var temp2 = self.loginOk;
  var temp3 = self.loginFail;
  ask("Ваш пароль?", temp1, temp2, temp3);
}
```

В функцию ask попадают две другие функции, которые никак не привязаны к объекту из которого их достали.

Чтобы сохранить this - надо воспользоваться одним из трех вариантов.

Вариант 1 - сделать функции вложенными:

```
checkPassword: function() {
  var self = this;
  ask("Ваш пароль?", self.password, loginOk, loginFail);

  function loginOk() {
      // здесь this потерялся, но переменная self сохраняет свое значение
  }

  function loginFail() {
      // здесь this потерялся, но переменная self сохраняет свое значение
  }
}
```

Вариант 2 - используйте bind:

```
ask("Ваш пароль?", this.password, this.loginOk.bind(this), this.loginFail.bind(this))
```

Вариант 3 - можно передать контекст в ask:

```
function ask(question, answer, ok, fail, ctx) {
  var result = prompt(question, '');
  if (result.toLowerCase() == answer.toLowerCase()) ok.call(ctx);
  else fail.call(ctx);
}

ask("Ваш пароль?", this.password, this.loginOk, this.loginFail, this)
```

Больше вариантов, включая современные, можно найти здесь: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/178779)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, функцию надо запускать, а ты просто передаешь на ее ссылку. Ты аргументом передаешь саму функцию, которая не запускается и ничего не делает

```js
"use strict";
var user = {
  login: 'Василий',
  password: '12345',

  loginOk: function() {
    alert(this.login + ' вошёл в сайт');
  },

  loginFail: function() {
    alert(this.login + ': ошибка входа');
  }
};

console.log(user.loginOk);

console.log(user.loginFail);

console.log(user.loginOk());

console.log(user.loginFail());
```