# Как скрыть форму ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Использую этот плагин https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Как мне скрыть форму после отправки, this hide() не получается. Форм несколько, поэтому мне нужно скрыть именно ту, которая заполнена

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".vacancies-form").validate({
            ignore: ":hidden",
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "sender.php",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                       $(this).hide();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success: function () {
  $(form).hide();
}
```