# Как правильно экспортировать переменные из es6 модуля?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

У меня есть модуль `timer.js`. У него есть метод `start`, который каждую секунду через `setInterval` вызывает метод `update` инкрементирующий переменную `seconds`.

Почему в коде ниже в консоли выводится 0 а не 3?
Как правильно шарить переменную в es6 модуле?

```
   import timer from './modules/timer'
    timer.start();
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(timer.seconds);
    }, 3000);
```

**timer.js**

```
let timer = null;
let seconds = 0;

function start() {
    timer = setInterval(update, 1000);
}

function stop() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function update() {
    seconds++;
}

export default {seconds, start, stop};
```

Для сборки я использую [laravel-mix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix) - это обертка над webpack для laravel. Не знаю важно ли это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы работаете в глобальной среде.

Ваши переменные из `timer.js` всегда будут с первоначальными значениями.

Иными словами вы каждый раз обнуляете переменную `timer` и `seconds`, вызывая объект `timer.[любая функция]`

Вы можете сделать экспорт класса или просто объекта, который будет включать в себе и переменную `timer`, и `seconds`.
Тогда ваша среда будет одна и все вносимые изменения будут доступны в том же скопе.

P.S. Возможно не смог словами объяснить суть, поэтому смотрите код ниже

Пример Object:

```
export default {
    timer: null,
    seconds: 0,
    start: function() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => this.update(), 1000)
    },
    stop: function() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
    },
    update: function() {
        this.seconds++
    }
};
```

Пример Class:

```
export default class Timer {
    timer = null;
    seconds = 0;
    start() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => this.update(), 1000)
    }
    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
    }
    update() {
        this.seconds++
    }
};

// Использование:
import Timer from './timer'
const timer = new Timer();
```

Comment: Спасибо это работает. А подскажите еще почему вот так не работает this.timer = setInterval(this.update, 1000); ? setInterval же вроде должен принимать не только анонимную функцию.

Comment: Про это можно почитать здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/Потеря-контекста-вызова

Comment: @diraria спасибо за ссылку