# Почему такие изменения в методе Start при прототипном наследовании?

Tags: javascript, наследование, замыкания, prototype, bind

Вопрос такой:Почему в функциональном стиле в setInterval render вызывается как обычно, а в прототипном используется вызов через замыкание?

И есть ли смысл использовать метод bind вместо замыкания через новую переменную self?

Код в функциональном стиле.:
function Clock(options) {

```js
var template = options.template;
  var timer;

  function render() {
    var date = new Date();

    var hours = date.getHours();
    if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;

    var min = date.getMinutes();
    if (min < 10) min = '0' + min;

    var sec = date.getSeconds();
    if (sec < 10) sec = '0' + sec;

    var output = template.replace('h', hours).replace('m', min).replace('s', sec);

    console.log(output);
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };

  this.start = function() {
    render();
    timer = setInterval(render, 1000);
```

Тот же код в прототипном стиле:

```js
function Clock(options) {
  this._template = options.template;
}

Clock.prototype._render = function render() {
  var date = new Date();

  var hours = date.getHours();
  if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;

  var min = date.getMinutes();
  if (min < 10) min = '0' + min;

  var sec = date.getSeconds();
  if (sec < 10) sec = '0' + sec;

  var output = this._template.replace('h', hours).replace('m', min).replace('s', sec);

  console.log(output);
};

Clock.prototype.stop = function() {
  clearInterval(this._timer);
};

Clock.prototype.start = function() {
  this._render();
  var self = this;
  this._timer = setInterval(function() {
    self._render();
  }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Вас интересует, можно ли во втором случае использовать что-то вроде `this._timer = setInterval(this._render, 1000)`? Или я неправильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Да,но я как понимаю кроме как использовать bind  других вариантов кроме замыкания -нет.Мне не понятно почему в функциональном стиле бинд и замыкание не нужны,а прототипном нужны.Якобы всё дело в контексте

Comment: Посмотрите ответ в этом вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/Потеря-контекста-вызова/536020#536020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Касательно первой части вопроса, почему нельзя при прототипном стиле использовать `this._timer = setInterval(this._render, 1000)`.

```js
function A() {
  let instanceVariable = 1;
  
  function _render() {
    console.log("Rendring A...");
    console.log(instanceVariable);
  }
  
  this.start = function() {
    setInterval(_render, 1000);
  }
}

function B() {
  this.instanceVariable = 1;
}

B.prototype._render = function() {
  console.log("Rendering B...");
  console.log(this.instanceVariable);
}

B.prototype.start = function() {
  setInterval(this._render, 1000);
}

new A().start();
new B().start();
```

Причина проста: потеря контекста. Можно видеть из примера с функцией `B`, что `_render` хотя и вызывается и нормально отрабатывает, но поскольку вызвана она в контексте глобального (в данном случае) объекта, то инстансную переменную внутри этой функции не видно.

Происходит так потому, что функции `setInterval` мы передали в качестве первого параметра функцию, которую хотим вызывать раз в секунду, то есть, грубо говоря, сам код функции. А о контексте `setInterval` ничего в момент вызова знать не будет.

Именно поэтому в вашем примере используется такая конструкция:

```
var self = this;
this._timer = setInterval(function() {
  self._render();
}, 1000);
```

Сначала сохраняется контекст, а потом функция `_render` вызывается уже непосредственно в правильном контексте.

Подобный подход на самом деле уже устаревший, и сейчас наилучшим решением будет воспользоваться стрелочной функцией:

```
// var self = this; // закомментировано, явно сохранять контекст более нет необходимости
this._timer = setInterval(() => { // стрелочная функция
  this._render(); // теперь здесь используем `this`
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Если у вас остались какие-то вопросы касательно моего объяснения, то прошу их задать здесь, чтобы я мог обновить ответ под ваши нужды. Сейчас все выглядит довольно сумбурно, потому что я не совсем понимаю, чего именно не понимаете *вы*.

Comment: Спасибо!Теперь всё ясно

Answer (score -1):

Может быть дело в том,что при прототипмном наследовании мы теряем возможность использовать локальные переменные как приватные свойства, у них больше нет общей области видимости с конструктором.По этому в функциональном наследовании мы не потеряем контекст при вызове метода render,он не ссылается на this,а в прототипном варианте render() ссылается на this._template. и из-за этого нужно привязывать контекст вызова, что мы и делаем через переменную self и метод apply. ведь при использовании setInterval контекст вызова теряется. Короче я походу бред тут сморозил)