# Почему Оборачивание события в таймаут уничтожает событие? Как этого избежать?

Tags: angular2

Ангуляр 7. Приложение "Список покупок". Столбец с дивами с товаром и цветовые кнопки для сортировки. Например "Картошка" и "Лук" можно покрасить одинаковым цветом, что расположит их при пересортировке рядом. Еще есть Крестик - признак "куплено". Элементы переставляются

```
css / diplay:flex / order:[вычисляемое].
```

Элементы сгенерированы с помощью `*ngFor`

Order меняется с помощью `[ngStyle]`

Все работает. Но, когда нажимаешь на сортировку, пользователю не очевидно, куда элемент мгновенно пропал. Я Решил перед сортировкой просчитать направление и сыграть небольшое движение `{margin-top: -70px; }` на `50ms`.

А подстановку настоящего положения отложить на 100ms. Событие }клик на дочернем элементе `shop.component.html`

передает на `shop.component.ts`

в функцию  `d(elem: any, sort: number)`

(себя-элемент, и новый номер сортировки)

После вычисления направления элементу сообщается новый стиль `{margin-top: -70px;}`

Потом генерируется событие: "Кнопку сорт нажали",

для передачи родительскому компоненту `app.component.ts`,

а оттуда в

```
data.service.ts
```

и сообщает объекту модели новые значения `{order:[]}`

Событие долетает быстрее, чем 50ms, что приводит к мгновенному перестроению, а потом на новом месте элемент исполняет маленький танец. Это не то, что я хотел. Если обернуть запуск события в таймер ДАЖЕ НУЛЕВОЙ:

```
setTimeout(function() {
              this.ColorBtnClicked.emit(elem);
       }, 0 );
```

То событие вообще не испускается.
Теперь, элемент ведет себя так как надо: он имитирует начало полета в нужную сторону и перестраивается, но не окрашивается в нужный цвет и не получает префикс типа 1)2)... -8) Номер сортировки (а это задача data.service.ts). А если убрать тайм аут, то событие выполняет свою работу (красит див и ставит префикс), но мгновенно, а потом элемент танцует на новом месте, где его и не видно за пределами экрана.

Попробую лаконично выложить код:

shop.component.html

```
 <div id="shopping" style="display: block;">
      <ul id="listingUL">
        <li *ngIf="!isFirst" class="item" [ngClass] = "{itemCrossedOut: item.done}" [ngStyle] ="{backgroundColor: 'var(--color' + ('' + item.order) + ')'}">

          <div class="main">
            <span class="itm">{{item.content}}</span>
            <button (click)="d(item, 9)" class="ok">X</button>
          </div>
          <div  class="orderDiv">
            <button (click)="d(item, 1)" class="orderBtn d1">1</button>
            <button (click)="d(item, 2)" class="orderBtn d2">2</button>
            <button (click)="d(item, 3)" class="orderBtn d3">3</button>
            <button (click)="d(item, 4)" class="orderBtn d4">4</button>
            <button (click)="d(item, 5)" class="orderBtn d5">5</button>
            <button (click)="d(item, 6)" class="orderBtn d6">6</button>
            <button (click)="d(item, 7)" class="orderBtn d7">7</button>
            <button (click)="d(item, 8)" class="orderBtn d8">8</button>
          </div>
        </li>
        </div>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

shop.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  EventEmitter,
  Output,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {Item} from '../item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shop-comp',
  templateUrl: './shop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shop.component.css']
  })

export class ShopComponent{
  @Input() shopData: Item[];

  @Output() ColorBtnClicked = new EventEmitter<any>();


    d(elem: any, sort: number) {
      let newDone;
      let dir: number; // направление

      // здесь вычисляем новое направление

      if (dir > 0) {elem.direction = '70px 0px -70px 0px';}
      else  if (dir < 0) {elem.direction = '-70px 0px 70px 0px';}


      // setTimeout(function() {
        elem.done = newDone;
        if (sort !== 9) {elem.order = sort; }
        this.ColorBtnClicked.emit(elem);
      // }, 100 );


      setTimeout(function() {
        elem.direction = '0px 0px 0px 0px';
      }, 200 );
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  title = 'Shop-Reminder-App';
  activeScreen = 'inp';
  // activeAdv = 'slp';
  listing = '';
  shopData = [];

  onClickScreenBtn(screen) {
    this.activeScreen = screen;
  }

  onlistingAreaChanged(listing) { // слушаем событие изменился listing и отправляем текст в DataService
    this.shopData = this.dataService.rebuildData(listing);
  }

  ColorBtnClicked() { // слушаем нажатие на цвето-сортировку
        this.listing = this.dataService.rebuildText();
}

  setOldText(obj: any) {
    let text = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
         text = text + obj[i].content + ',';
    }
    this.shopData = this.dataService.rebuildData(text);
  }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.setOldText(this.shopData);
  }
}
```

data.service.ts

```
import {Item} from './item';

export class DataService {
  private data: Item[] = [];

  // getData(): Item[] {
  //   return this.data;
  // }


  rebuildData(text) {

        this.data = [];
       // присваиваем прорядок согласно номеру 1)-8), если он есть

    return this.data;
  }

  rebuildText() { 
                 //Заглавие, номера 1)2)3)4)5)6)7)8) done(х)
    let text = '';
      // после нажатия на сортировку модифицируем список:  
      //Заглавие, номера 1)2)3)4)5)6)7)8) done(х)    
    return text;
  }
}
```

item.ts

```
export class Item {
  constructor(
    public order: number,
    public content: string,
    public done: boolean,
    public direction: string,
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout((function() {
  this.ColorBtnClicked.emit(elem);
}).bind(this), 0);
```

или

```
setTimeout(() => this.ColorBtnClicked.emit(elem), 0);
```

или

```
setTimeout(function(context) {
  context.ColorBtnClicked.emit(elem);
}, 0, this);
```

Comment: или `new EventEmitter(true)`

Comment: Большое спасибо. Первый же вариант решил задачу.                         
                                                                 setTimeout((function() {
  this.ColorBtnClicked.emit(elem);
}).bind(this), 0);                                                                                                                                                                           
Теперь мне надо почитать об этом теорию, потому, что я их не различаю. Вы могли бы дать ссылки на где почитать. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @A.Victor https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0