# Internet Explorer 8 не вызывается jquery ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Добавляю совместимость интернет-магазина с Internet Explorer 8,
для этого использую версию JQuery 1.10.2.

При нажатии кнопки добавления товара в корзину отрабатывает код:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: this.ajaxSuccess,
    error: this.ajaxError
});
```

Товар успешно добавляется в корзину (на сервере), но функция `ajaxSuccess` не вызывается.

Как фиксить?

Comment: В качестве фикса советую серьёзно поговорить с тем, кто вынуждает Вас заниматься такими вещами. IE8 - устаревший браузер, не надо его поддерживать ни под каким видом.

Comment: А в каком контексте это все вызывается? Возможно, какая-то проблема с привязкой по `this`. Пробовали без `this`? Пробовали *подписаться* на `complete`?

Comment: А ты уверен, что в других браузерах вызывается?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy в других браузерах - да. Но в них я привязываю функции к \_\_proto\_\_ объекта виджета, может быть дело в этом? https://pastecode.xyz/view/879ddf77

Comment: 1. [mcve] 2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL1gj.png 3. Уже по описанию ясно, что фигня

Comment: @Kir_Antipov так как в IE8 нету \_\_proto\_\_, то я не привязывал this к контексту вызова функций. Верно, я не передал контекст, нужно в конструкторе было привязать через bind как и для других браузеров, с отличием только в том, что в левой части выражения не нужно __proto__. Спасибо.

Comment: `$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: this.ajaxSuccess,
    error: this.ajaxError
}).done(//todo); попробуйте`