# Это магия callback-ов?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Работаю с `Vuejs`, наткнулся скорей всего на магию `callback-ов`, как мне кажется.

```js
const steps = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    steps: stepsList,
    currentStep: 0,
    prevStep: function() {
      // wtf is here
      console.log(this, steps)
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<button class="prev-btn" @click="prevStep">Назад</button>
```

Вот небольшая часть кода с которой имеются проблемы. Не могу понять, почему `this` равен `Window`, а `steps (по сути это свойство объект)` равно объекту `Vue`, который я создал.

Через "стрелки" тоже посмотрел, результат тот же.

Где в моих знаниях пробел?

Comment: Как вызывается эта функция?

Comment: Повесил обработчик события через vuejs @click

Comment: Может, покажете больше кода - если он, конечно, не секретный?

Comment: Добавил еще кода

Comment: Если вы хотите обратиться к свойству объекта - надо писать object.property, а steps - это вы обращаетесь к переменной. В данном случае это созданный объект, т.к. `const steps = new Vue({`. Ну а `this` это `this` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Где в моих знаниях пробел?

[Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020/256824).

```
let data = {
  steps: [{
    item: "1"
  }],
  prevStep: function() {
    console.log(this, steps)
  }
}

const steps = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: data
})
```

> Где в моих знаниях пробел?

Определяйте методы в объекте [`methods`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9).

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

const steps = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    steps: [{
      item: "1"
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    prevStep: function(event) {
      console.log(this.steps)
    }
  }
})

steps.prevStep()
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button class="prev-btn" @click="prevStep">Назад</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
```