# NODEJS + Socket.io + VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

Доброго времени суток.

Использую VUEJS вместе с Socket.io .
Так как мне нужно передать данные, я их передаю в Created: function() во VUEJS:

```
    const socket = io('xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000', {
        query: {
            clientid: this.clientid
        }
    });
```

Но в Methods тогда ошибка возникает, мол [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: socket is not defined". 
Как мне сделать так, чтобы можно было передать данные, но и при этом не возникало ошибки?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/256824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак.

Я создал метод connect(), где прописал это:

```
    return socket = io('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000', {
        query: {
            clientid: this.clientid
        }
    });
```

В Created прописал

> this.connect();

и все заработало.