# вывод значения vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

подскажите, где ошибся, вывожу значение из usd и ничего не показывает

```
<template>
            <div class="box-dop">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="item full">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="politic" id="politic" value="1" v-model="form.politic">
                            <label for="politic">С  <a href="">Правилами</a>  размещения рекламы полностью согласен(на) {{usd}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-blue" @click.prevent="paySystemsShow(activec)">Выбрать способ оплаты</button>
                <div class="box-pay list-pay" :class="{'active':showpay}">
                    <div class="p-item" v-for="paysystem in paysystems">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img :src="'/storage/images/uploads/pay/'+paysystem.icon" :alt="paysystem.title">
                            <span>{{ paySystemCost(paysystem.procent,paysystem.price_dop,paysystem.current) }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        el: '#add_catalog_link',
        data: function(){
            return {
                max: 160,
                maxdescription: 60,
                paysystems: [],
                showpay: false,
                activec: 0,
                sUsd: '',
                form: {
                    url: '',
                    description: '',
                    politic: false,
                    days: 5,
                    cost: 45,
                    status: 0
                }
            }
        },
        computed: {
            costOrder: function() {
                var result = 0,
                    countDays = this.form.days,
                    highlight = this.form.status;
                if (highlight === 0) result = countDays * 9; else result = countDays * 14;
                return result
            },
            usd(){
                console.log(this.sUsd)
                return this.sUsd
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getPaySystems()
            this.paySystemCost()
            this.getUsd()
        },
        methods: {
            getUsd(){
                $.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", function(data) {
                    this.sUsd = data.Valute.USD.Value
                    console.log(this.sUsd)
                });
            },
            getPaySystems(){
                axios.get('/paysystems/getlist')
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.paysystems = response.data
                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
            paySystemsShow(tmp){
                if ( tmp === 0 ){
                    this.showpay = true;
                    this.activec = 1;
                } else {
                    this.showpay = false;
                    this.activec = 0;
                }
            },
            paySystemCost(procent,price,current){

                var sCurrent = null,
                    sCost = 0;
                if (current === 'RUB'){
                    sCurrent = 'RUB'
                    sCost = this.costOrder
                }
                if (current === 'USD'){
                    sCurrent = 'USD'
                    console.log(this.sUsd)
                    //sCost = (this.costOrder / this.currentUsd()).toFixed(2);
                    sCost = this.sUsd;
                }
                if (procent > 0 && price > 0){
                    return sCost + sCurrent+ '(' + price + ' р. + ' + procent + '% )'
                }
                if (procent > 0 && price === 0){
                    return sCost + sCurrent+ '('+ '+ ' + procent + '%)'
                }
                if (procent === 0 && price > 0){
                    return sCost + sCurrent +'('+ price + ' р.)'
                }
                if (procent === 0 && price === 0){
                    return sCost + sCurrent
                }
                //var costProcent = 0;
                //if (procent > 0) costProcent = (this.costOrder * procent) / 100
                //console.log('cost procent - ' + costProcent)
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать лишние теги закрывающиеся ` </form></div>` перед закрывающим `</template>`

Comment: **[Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/256824)**, **[Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/256824)**

Comment: перепробовал все, но не отображается переменная

Comment: при чем что в консоле он выводит курс getUsd(){
                $.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", function(data) {
                    this.sUsd = data.Valute.USD.Value
                    console.log(this.sUsd)
                });
            },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в обработчике `this` НЕ экземпляр vue, а что-то другое

```
$.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", function(data) {
  this.sUsd = data.Valute.USD.Value     // <-- вот здесь
  console.log(this.sUsd)
});
```

Попробуйте залогировать не `this.sUsd`, а `this` и посмотрите что в нём.

---

Чтобы заработало, надо использовать [стрелочную функцию](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function#funktsii-strelki-ne-imeyut-svoego-this)

```
$.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", (data) => {
  this.sUsd = data.Valute.USD.Value
});
```

Или сохранить контекст

```
const vm = this
$.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", function(data) {
  vm.sUsd = data.Valute.USD.Value
});
```