# почему разный результат?

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict"

function CoffeeMachine(power) {

  this.waterAmount = 0;

  // физическая константа - удельная теплоёмкость воды для getBoilTime
  var WATER_HEAT_CAPACITY = 4200;

  // расчёт времени для кипячения
  function getBoilTime() {
    return this.waterAmount * WATER_HEAT_CAPACITY * 80 / power; // ошибка!
  }

  // что делать по окончании процесса
  function onReady() {
    alert( 'Кофе готов!' );
  }

  this.run = function() {
    setTimeout(onReady, getBoilTime());
  };

}

var coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(1000);
coffeeMachine.waterAmount = 200;

coffeeMachine.run();
```

```js
function CoffeeMachine(power) {
  this.waterAmount = 0;
  var WATER_HEAT_CAPACITY = 4200;

  function getBoilTime() {
    return this.waterAmount * WATER_HEAT_CAPACITY * 80 / power;
  }

  function onReady() {
    alert( 'Кофе готов!' );
  }

  this.run = function() {
    setTimeout(onReady, getBoilTime.call(this));
  };

}

// создаю кофеварку, мощностью 100000W чтобы кипятила быстро
var coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(100000);
coffeeMachine.waterAmount = 200;

coffeeMachine.run();
```

Comment: Попробуй обернуть return в скобки

Comment: А вы попробовали перед тем как дать ответ?

Comment: Grundy с дубльмолотом на вас нет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020

Comment: @Caxihise, все есть :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вызов `getBoilTime` без указания контекста вызова вызывает эту функцию в глобальном контексте, у которого нет свойства `waterAmount`, что в `"use strict"` приводит к ошибке.

Comment: можно подробнее ?

Comment: в глобальном контексте,  свойства waterAmount есть

Comment: я правильно понял что coffeeMachine.run(); вызывает getBoilTime() в глобальном контексте где this.waterAmount;  this указывает на window  где в строгом режиме будет unedfuned  ?

Comment: тогда getBoilTime.call(this));  call будет указывать на объект coffeeMachine  ?

Comment: @user345125 - да