# Как использовать в конструкторе метод в методе с таймаутом?

Tags: javascript, методы, конструктор

Вызываю метод sayMeow() в методе voice() без таймаута. Все норм

```
   function catTemplate(cat) {
    this.word = 'meow',
    this.sayMeow = function(){
        console.log(this.word);
    }
    this.voice = function(){
       this.sayMeow();
    };
}
var Barsik = new catTemplate;
Barsik.voice();
```

С таймаутом not a function

```
 function catTemplate(cat) {
    this.word = 'meow',
    this.sayMeow = function(){
        console.log(this.word);
    }
    this.voice = function(){
        setTimeout(this.sayMeow , 1000)
    };
}
var Barsik = new catTemplate;
Barsik.voice();
```

Comment: В `setTimeout` `this` уже __другой__.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Вот я и хочу привязать this внутри таймаута к catTemplate

Comment: Ну так откройте дубликат и прочтите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит потому что теряется контекст (В данном случае `this` Вашего класса). Для того чтобы исправить данную проблему необходимо осуществить привязку контекста к данному методу используя `bind()`. [Привязка контекста к функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind)

```js
 function catTemplate(cat) {
    this.word = 'meow',
    this.sayMeow = function(){
        console.log(this.word);
    }
    this.voice = function(){
        setTimeout(this.sayMeow.bind(this) , 1000)
    };
}
var Barsik = new catTemplate;
Barsik.voice();
```

Comment: Да, отлично, именно это и было нужно