# Ошибка при создании слайдера через объект

Tags: javascript

При запуске кода изображения не изменяются - указывается ошибка.

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

```
    let slider = {
        i: 0,
        images: [],
        time: 3000,
        slide: document.querySelector('.slide'),
        add(){
            this.start();
            this.images.push('image/legnica_1.jpg');
            this.images.push('image/39c0100a3a9241e9460cf7b37f99f011.jpg');
            this.images.push('image/images.jpg');
            this.slide.src = this.images[this.i];
        },

        start() {
            if(this.i < this.images.length-1){
                this.i++;
            }
            else{
                this.i=0;
            }
            setTimeout(this.start, this.time);
        }

}

slider.add();
```

Comment: потеря контекста, при вызове `start` в  `setTimeout` `this` уже равен `window`, а не `slider` - https://learn.javascript.ru/bind

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)