# Ошибка vue is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
        mounted(){
          $('#addNewUser').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
           this.fetchArticles();
          })
        },
       methods: {
         fetchArticles(){
           alert("OK")
        },
```

Отслеживаю закрытие модального окна Bootstrap и пытаюсь вызвать функцию, но выдает ошибку **this.fetchArticles is not a function**

Comment: вы "скрестили" vue и jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас потеря контекста. Краткий ответ.

```
$('#addNewUser').on('hidden.bs.modal', () => this.fetchArticles())
```

[Подробнее здесь.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536020/4514)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так

```
$('#addNewUser').on('hidden.bs.modal', this.fetchArticles)
```

Comment: У вас потеря контекста в вопросе и в ответе его тоже не будет. 
Сейчас заработало потому что функция alert глобальная и ей не нужен контекст.