# как сохранить переменную из блока success ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/get-region-coordinator?id='+platform_id,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var reg_coords = data;
            }
        });
...

Как вот здесь использовать reg_coords например 
$.each(reg_coords,function(k,v){
....
});
```

Просто объясните как контекст работает) я ловлю  `reg_coords is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно `$.each` писать непосредственно в колбэке например.

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k,v){
        ....
    });
}
```

Либо сделать функцию и на нее сослаться:

```
success:test
// ...
// ...
// ...

function test(data) {
    $.each(data,function(k,v){
    ....
    });
}
```

---

Так же есть другие способы. Смотрите: **[Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/191482)**

Comment: Спасибо огромное! пошел читать