# Uncaught TypeError: this.jhdjjjgfldfgd is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Уже устал получать такие сообщения. Я этот vue вообще не пойму он одни функции вызывает другие нет такая ошибка. Все функции находятся в methods. Думал может что то конфликтует с чем сделал рандомное имя функции. Я не понимаю что не так?

```
 export default {
      props: ["isCheckMinerals", "timeIgnition", "step"],
      data() {
        return {
          stop: null,
          isClicked: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        clickBtn: function () {
          this.clLeftToRight();
        },
        clLeftToRight: function () {
          this.animCircleLeftToRight(20, 20);
        },
    
        jhdjjjgfldfgd () {
            console.log("");
          /*clearInterval(this.stop);
          this.stop = null;
          if(progress >= 100) { //значит закончили
              consol.log("finish");
          } else {
              consol.log("nefinish");
          }  */
        },
        animCircleLeftToRight: function (iteration, border = 0, step = 1) {
          if (this.stop !== null) {
            clearInterval(this.stop);
            this.stop = null;
          }
          var elem = document.getElementById("mdonut");
          if (border > 0) {
            var attr0 = elem.getAttribute("stroke-dasharray") + "";
            let arr0 = attr0.split(" ");
            var rNum0 = Number.parseInt(arr0[1]);
            border = rNum0 - border;
          }
          this.stop = setInterval(function () {
            var attr = elem.getAttribute("stroke-dasharray") + "";
            let arr = attr.split(" ");
            var lNum = Number.parseInt(arr[0]);
            lNum += step;
            var rNum = 100 - lNum;
            if (rNum >= border && rNum >= 0) {
              elem.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", lNum + " " + rNum);
            } else {
              this.jhdjjjgfldfgd(); //вот тут постоянно ошибка
            }
          }, iteration);
        },
    
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: У функции, которая запихнута в setInterval, значением `this` будет объект `window`

Comment: Спасибо. Кажется понял. Но как же мне вызвать?

Comment: Все кажется понял, надо будет ответ написать, спасибо большое я java script очень плохо знаю.