# Как вызвать метод класса из колбэк функции

Tags: javascript, классы, callback

У меня вопрос:
как вызвать метод, который находится в калбэк функции?

Я сделал пример https://jsfiddle.net/novoto4in/cv9uogpa/12/

```
class D {
    constuctor(aa) {
    this.aa = aa
    console.log(aa)
  }
  
  test() {
    return 'hi'
  }
  
  open() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.setEventListeners)
  }
  
  setEventListeners() {
    console.log(' 1 ')
    //this.test()  // не работает
    //console.log(this.test()) // ошибка
  }
}

const quadro = new D('div')
quadro.open()
```

При клике мыши появляеься надпись "1" , а как сделать, чтобы появлялся текст из метода test?

Comment: в вашем случае `document.addEventListener('click', () => { this.setEventListeners() })`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/

Comment: Может и дубликат