# Реакивность VUE или как следить за обьтектом

Tags: vue.js, vue3

[Проект расположил вот тут](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-surf-15ey6?file=/src/main.ts).

Есть объект

```js
let layout = {
  childs: [
    {
      id: "gdy49639292",
      type: "Place",
      mess: "hello"
    },
    ...
  ],
  add: function (obj: Place) {
    this.childs.push(obj);
  }
};
```

Этот объект рендерит `vue`. У приложения есть метод `@app add` который вызывает метод `@obj add` объекта.

В `data()` добавляю свойство

```
data(){
  return {  childs:this.layout.childs };
}
```

и таким образом рендерится компонент:

```
<Place
  v-for="data in  childs"
  :key ="data.id"
  :data="data"
></Place>
```

По нажатию на кнопку вызывается метод `@app add`:

```
add() {
  let new_components = this._createComponent();
  this.layout.add(new_components);
}
```

При этом новый элемент доступен и у `@app childs`, но новый элемент не рендерится. Тк объекты у vue проксируются, так понимаю не вызывается сетер.
Как добиться того что бы новые объекты рендерились?

---

Так работать будет:

```
this.childs = Object.assign({}, this.layout.childs);
```

так же, как и если повесить счетчик на компонент, но так не надо.

---

Добавляю новые элементы с помощь метода объекта `@obj add` тк он будет еще нужен для дальнейшей работы с ним вне приложения vue

Comment: _«В `data()` добавляю свойство `childs:this.layout.childs;`»_ - неправильно. Вопросы для проработки допущенной ошибки: **1.** На что указывает `this` в выражении значения свойства? **2.** Допустимо ли использовать `;` в литерале объекта?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: @yar85 Подредактировал вопрос. Неправильно так делать или Вы про синтаксис. Если второй, то в проекте не так `{childs:this.layout.childs;}`. **1** `this` указывает на объект компонента, причем здесь потеря контекста? **2** не допустимо.

Comment: В том и дело, что **`this` здесь не указывает на объект vue-компонента**... в момент выполнения `data`, такого объекта еще не существует (равно как и объекта литерала, в котором объявлен метод `data`). Об этом написано и в официальной справке Vue, и в ответах по ссылке на связанный вопрос, комментом выше. Изучи, пожалуйста. А те два пронумерованных вопроса - они для самостоятельного изучения предмета ошибки, и последующей самопроверки: здесь на них отвечать не нужно, на них желательно ответить самому себе :) Второй оказался вызван опечаткой, так что остался только первый...

Comment: @yar85 Со вторым вопросом разберусь, а вот с первым требуется помощь, линтер говорит, что указывает на `CreateComponentPublicInstance`. VUE только учу по этому если оставите ссылку (_'Об этом написано и в справке Vue'_) будет здорово.

Comment: Помощь уже предоставлена выше (объяснения по ссылке, в ответах на слинкованный вопрос). А ссылка на страницу документации Vue - вот: [Экземпляр Vue и диаграмма жизненного цикла](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) (это первая глава учебника, если что).

Answer (score 0):

В `data()` надо присваивать не дочерние элементы, а сам объект:

```
data(){
  return {  obj:this.layout }; // [old]: return {  childs:this.layout.childs };
}
```

соответственно, рендер немного измениться:

```
<Place
  v-for="data in obj.childs" // [old]: v-for="data in  childs"
  :key ="data.id"
  :data="data"
></Place>
```

В дальнейшем как советует [документация](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/reactivity.html#proxy-vs-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C):

> Хорошей практикой будет никогда не сохранять ссылку на оригинальный объект и работать только с реактивной версией.

Измениться метод `@app add`:

```
add() {
  let new_components = this._createComponent();
  this.obj.add(new_components); // [old]: this.layout.add(new_components);
}
```

После того как приложение выполнило свою функцию экспортировать объект.

> Добавляю новые элементы с помощь метода объекта @obj add тк он будет еще нужен для дальнейшей работы с ним вне приложения vue