# Почему выходит ошибка?

Tags: javascript

```js
class Calc {
    constructor() {
    this.Plus = document.querySelector('.plus');
    this.Minus = document.querySelector('.minus');
    this.NumberOne = document.getElementById('numone');
    this.NumberTwo = document.getElementById('numtwo');   
    }

    start() {
        this.Plus.addEventListener('click', function () {
            NumOne = this.NumberOne.value;
            NumTwo = this.NumberTwo.value;
            alert(NumOne + NumTwo)
        });
     
    }
}
  

let calc = new Calc;
calc.start();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <button class="plus">+</button>
        <button class="minus">-</button>
    </div>
    <input id="numtwo" type="number" value="0" />
    <input id="numtwo" type="number" value="0"/>
    

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Какая ошибка у вас выходит?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок куча:

1. Идентификатора `numone` не было
2. Вместо `'click', function () {`  надо стрелочную функцию. Т.к. контекст теряется **[см. тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/191482)**
3. Для `NumOne` и `NumTwo` надо делать объявление переменных, а не брать с потолка

```js
class Calc {
    constructor() {
        this.Plus = document.querySelector('.plus');
        this.Minus = document.querySelector('.minus');
        this.NumberOne = document.getElementById('numone');
        this.NumberTwo = document.getElementById('numtwo');   
    
    }

    start() {
        this.Plus.addEventListener('click',  () => {
            let NumOne = +this.NumberOne.value;
            let NumTwo = +this.NumberTwo.value;
            alert(NumOne + NumTwo)
        });
     
    }
}
  

let calc = new Calc;
calc.start();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <button class="plus">+</button>
        <button class="minus">-</button>
    </div>
    <input id="numone" type="number" value="0" />
    <input id="numtwo" type="number" value="0"/>
    

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```